# Node.js return result of multiple asynchronous yield synchronously

Tags: node.js, promise, ecmascript-6, yield, rethinkdb

I am using rethinkDB with node.js. The following request works fine :

```
function myFn () {
 return co(function *() {
        let query;

        query = yield r.db("my-db")
            .table("app")
            .filter(r.row("id").eq(id))
            .run(conn);

        return query.toArray();
    });
}
```

I would like to return the result of multiple `yield` asynchronously, however the following fails :

```
function myFn () {
 return co(function *() {
        let query, query2;

        query = r.db("my-db")
            .table("app")
            .filter(r.row("id").eq(id))
            .run(conn);


        query2 = r.db("my-db")
            .table("app")
            .filter(...)
            .run(conn);

        return yield {q1 : query, q2 : query2};
    });
}
```

Then I have to call `toArray()` on each element, so on the calling function I do :

```
 // using ramda.js
  var res = R.map((el) => {
            return el.toArray();
        }, yield myFn);
```

However I get :

```
{
  "q1": {
    "isFulfilled": false,
    "isRejected": false
  },
  "q2": {
    "isFulfilled": false,
    "isRejected": false
  }
}
```

Something odd too :

```
 // this works perfectly
 return q.toArray();

 // this returns the following :
 return {q: q.toArray()};
 "q": {
   "isFulfilled": true,
   "isRejected": false,
   "fulfillmentValue": [  ...  ]
  }
```

I suspect I am missing something about the way `yield` works, so how can I return the fulfilled result of multiple `yield` results ?

Comment: How does it fail exactly? Do you get an error message? Do you get a different result than expected?

Comment: `yield { q1: r.db(" "), q2: r.db(" ")};`.

Comment: @nils I updated my question, thanks.

Comment: @torazaburo I'm not sure what you mean by that ?

Comment: I mean, if you return an object, then each property's value will be waited on in parallel, and the yield will "return" when all values have resolved, evaluating to parallel object whose properties' values are the promises' resolved values. In other words, do not yield the individual values, and then yield again an object of the yields; instead, yield once ,with a single object containing all the asynchronous elements.

Comment: @torazaburo right, I did that (and updated my question), but still get ```{
"isFulfilled": false,
"isRejected": false
}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I asked the same question on the [`reThinkDB google groups`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rethinkdb/SxNGCw6bwpE) :

To quote Ryan Paul :

> Your original attempt was actually really close, there were just two
>   things that you need to add:
>
> - You need to yield the queries individually
> - And you need to convert to array in the query if you don’t want to get cursors
>
> Here’s a working example with the coroutine and yield:
>
> ```
> function myFn() {
>   return co(function*() {
>     var conn = yield r.connect();
>     var query1 = yield r.db("test").table("fellowship")
>                         .filter({species: "hobbit"})
>                         .coerceTo("array").run(conn);
>
>     var query2 = yield r.db("test").table("fellowship")
>                         .filter({species: "human"})
>                         .coerceTo("array").run(conn);
>
>     conn.close();
>
>     return {q1: query1, q2: query2};
>   });
> }
> ```
>
> It’s also pretty simple to do without the coroutines and yield, and as
>   long as you use a promise library like bluebird. Here’s how I would do
>   it:
>
> ```
> function myFn1() {
>   return r.connect().then(conn => {
>     return bluebird.all([
>       r.db("test").table("fellowship")
>        .filter({species: "hobbit"})
>        .coerceTo("array").run(conn),
>       r.db("test").table("fellowship")
>        .filter({species: "human"})
>        .coerceTo("array").run(conn)
>     ]).then(items => ({q1: items[0], q2: items[1]}));
>   });
> }
> ```

Comment: OK, so `.coerceTo("array")` was the missing part in my answer. Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 1):

`yield` doesn't work with objects that contain promises - it only works with promises itself. Instead of `return yield {q1: query, q2: query2};` you'd have to do

```
return {q1: yield query, q2: yield query2};
```

However, that is kinda problematic as errors in `query2` will not be thrown until `query` is done. So if you don't [just want to sequentially execute them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24193595/1048572), you will have to use `Promise.all` to await a collection of promises "in parallel":

```
var [q1, q2] = yield Promise.all([query, query2]);
return {q1, q2};
```

(Depending on the promise lib you're using, there might also be a helper function to treat objects as collections, not only arrays)

Comment: The first approach still returns ```{
    "isFulfilled": false,
    "isRejected": false
  }```, while the second approach (Promise.all) still returns rethink Cursors (```[ Cursor {
    _type: 3,
    _eachCb: [Function],
    _conn: 
     TcpConnection {
       host: 'localhost',
       port: 28015,
       db: undefined,
       authKey: '',
       timeout: 20,
       ssl: false,
       outstandingCallbacks: [Object],....```

Comment: Hm, that doesn't look like `run()` returns a promise. Should you maybe rather `yield` the result of `.toArray()`? I'm not exactly familiar with rethink, but it doesn't look like Cursors are yieldable or thenable.

Comment: `run()` returns a Cursor, my understanding is that it can be used with yield as in my first example (also there https://rethinkdb.com/blog/rethinkdbdash-iojs/).

Comment: Hm, their examples only use commands like `create` or `insert`, where `run()` might directly return a promise (for nothing?). I'll assume that `filter().run()` returns a Cursor or a Promise for a Cursor, and `toArray()` then returns a Promise for an Array. Can you try to `yield` or `.all([…])` either `query.toArray()` or `(yield query).toArray()` instead?

Comment: I don't actually, not sure if there is something official about this (I am pretty new to rethink).