# Is await Promise.all() equivalent to an array [await, await]?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I wonder if the two following pieces of JavaScript code are equivalent:

Using `await Promise.all`:

`[foo, bar] = await Promise.all([getFoo(), getBar()])`

Using an array with `await`:

```
[foo, bar] = [
  await getFoo(),
  await getBar()
]
```

Comment: It would be cleaner to answer "yes" rather than to point to 3 questions that ask how to run promises in parallel. My question is about the equivalence of the syntax, not how to parallelize promises

Comment: Actually, reading the great MDN, it looks like the answer is "no": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Do_not_confuse_await_for_Promise.all

Comment: The note has been removed and replaced with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Do_not_confuse_await_for_Promisethen

Comment: The answer is... no, these are categorically not equivalent. There is a solid explanation of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45285129/any-difference-between-await-promise-all-and-multiple-await/54291660#54291660). TLDR: the failure modes are different.