# Unhandled promise rejection?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

[This example (repl.it)](https://repl.it/@ouroborus/ItchyWorthySandbox) (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45286517/367865)) looks to me like it follows all the rules regarding promises. Yet running it logs an exception regarding an unhandled promise rejection with the associated console message. (This also happens in FF, Chrome, and Node v10.)

The try/catch block is clearly there and wraps the rejected promise, so what's going on and how would I fix it?

```
async function example() {
  const start = Date.now()
  let i = 0
  function res(n) {
    const id = ++i
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve()
        console.log(`res #${id} called after ${n} milliseconds`, Date.now() - start)
      }, n)
    })
  }

  function rej(n) {
    const id = ++i
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        reject()
        console.log(`rej #${id} called after ${n} milliseconds`, Date.now() - start)
      }, n)
    })
  }

  try {
    const delay1 = res(3000)
    const delay2 = res(2000)
    const delay3 = rej(1000)

    const data1 = await delay1
    const data2 = await delay2
    const data3 = await delay3
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`await finished`, Date.now() - start)
  }
}

example()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that, at the point that the `rej` call rejects, the interpreter hasn't yet gotten to a line that `await`s the promise created by `rej`, so the rejected Promise is just that, a rejected Promise, rather than *a Promise that the current thread is `await`ing*:

```
try {
  const delay1 = res(3000)
  const delay2 = res(2000)
  const delay3 = rej(1000)

  const data1 = await delay1
  // The interpreter is paused on the line above when `rej` rejects
  const data2 = await delay2
  const data3 = await delay3
```

So, the behavior is the same as if a rejected Promise is declared without a `catch` handler. (Errors thrown by Promises will only be caught in an `async` function if they're `await`ed *at the point at which the Promise rejects* - otherwise, it'll just result in an unhandled promise rejection.)

I'd suggest either declaring Promises at the same point that you `await` them:

```
const data1 = await res(3000)
```

(note: the above method's timing won't be the same as the original code)

or use `await Promise.all` for all Promises, which means that the `Promise` the interpreter is currently `await`ing will throw (and thereby enter the `catch` block) as soon as *one* of the Promises rejects:

```
const [data1, data2, data3] = await Promise.all([
  res(3000),
  res(2000),
  rej(1000)
]);
```

```js
async function example() {
  const start = Date.now()
  let i = 0
  function res(n) {
    const id = ++i
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve()
        console.log(`res #${id} called after ${n} milliseconds`, Date.now() - start)
      }, n)
    })
  }
  
  function rej(n) {
    const id = ++i
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        reject()
        console.log(`rej #${id} called after ${n} milliseconds`, Date.now() - start)
      }, n)
    })
  }
  
  try {
    const [data1, data2, data3] = await Promise.all([
      res(3000),
      res(2000),
      rej(1000),
    ]);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`error caught: await finished`, Date.now() - start)
  }
}

example()
```

To do additional work while the three Promises are ongoing, and catch errors from those Promises as well as from the main thread, pass a *fourth* item to the `Promise.all`, an IIFE that does the additional work you want to do:

```js
async function example() {
  const start = Date.now()
  let i = 0
  function res(n) {
    const id = ++i
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve()
        console.log(`res #${id} called after ${n} milliseconds`, Date.now() - start)
      }, n)
    })
  }
  
  function rej(n) {
    const id = ++i
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        reject()
        console.log(`rej #${id} called after ${n} milliseconds`, Date.now() - start)
      }, n)
    })
  }
  
  try {
    const [data1, data2, data3] = await Promise.all([
      res(3000),
      res(2000),
      rej(1000),
      (() => {
        console.log('doing work...');
      })()
    ]);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`error caught: await finished`, Date.now() - start)
  }
}

example()
```

Comment: Separating the calls and the `await` like in the original example allows something to be done while the async stuff is working. It seems like you're saying that it's not possible to do this kind of separation without resorting to `.catch()`?

Comment: If you want to do additional things while still catching errors thrown by the three Promises, use the `Promise.all` method (plus a fourth non-Promise that does whatever other stuff you want to do), see edit. No need for `.catch` in addition to `} catch`