# async/await return undefined value

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await, undefined

I've searched for a solution but I was not able to implement it.

```
async processMAC(macs){
    let datos = [];
    for(let x in macs){
      await this.ipdataService.getMacsSaData(macs[x]).subscribe(data =>{ 
        datos.push(data)
      }
    )}
    return datos;   
  }


this.processMAC(macs).then(result => {//I want to work with result but it is undefined}
```

Comment: `await thing.subscribe(...)` doesn't make sense, a subscriber isn't a promise.

Comment: Indeed, look up the differences between Promises and Observables

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Promises

```
async processMAC(macs){
    let datos = [];
    for(let x in macs){
       datos.push(await this.ipdataService.getMacsSaData(macs[x])
    )}
    return datos;   
}
```

Or if you want to execute `getMacsSaData` in parallel

```
function processMAC(macs){
    return Promise.all(macs.map(mac => this.ipdataService.getMacsSaData(mac))) 
}
```

Comment: Really not equivalent. The first example will await `this.ipdataService.getMacsSaData(macs[x])` one by one. It's async but will take `n * x` amount of time if you'd measure the whole function. The second example does the requests in parallel and returns a promise that resolves when they're all finished. The second example lacks `async/await` as well. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45286517/3410196

Answer (score 0):

Weird, thought there might be some errors in the example code snippet, not sure if this will work:

```
let macsSaData = await this.ipdataService.getMacsSaData(macs[x]);
macsSaData.subscribe(data => { 
    datos.push(data)
}
```

Might also be able to put a breakpoint in the callback seeing if the correct data has been pushed into the array.