# Best way to fetch data from many tables in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, async-await, sequelize.js, es6-promise

If I have a view in my (mvc project) contains data from many tables in the database, what is the best way to fetch them without getting into the nested tree of doom

```
Model1.findAll().then(model1Data => {
  Model2.findAll().then(model2Data => {
    Model3.findAll().then(model3Data => {
      Modeln.findAll().then(modelnData => {
        res.render('view', {
          model1Data: model1Data,
          model2Data: model2Data,
          model3Data: model3Data,
          modelnData: modelnData
        });
      })
    })
  })
})
```

**Note**: the above query has no where clauses, joins, or any other conditions

Comment: If you have Sequelize Associations beetwin your Models, you can use Include to extract all the data [link](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#relations-associations)

If not, you can consider have a separated folder that contains all your models logic and call each required function, also, this should be helpful if you need show some info in other views (not all data)

Comment: also async / await syntax should work on that case

Comment: Already I have a separated folder for the models logic, but the same problem will happens when I call each one because the returned value will be promise and I have to use nesting to can use them at all

Comment: @vivek-doshi answer should work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you can use 2 ways either `Promise.all()` or `async/await` :

**Promise.all() :**

```
const promises = [
    Model1.findAll(),
    Model2.findAll(),
    Model3.findAll(),
    Modeln.findAll()
]

Promise.all(promises).then((data) => {
    res.render('view', data );
});
```

**Async/await :**

```
let model1Data = await Model1.findAll();
let model2Data = await Model2.findAll();
let model3Data = await Model3.findAll();
let modelnData = await Modeln.findAll();
res.render('view', {
    model1Data: model1Data,
    model2Data: model2Data,
    model3Data: model3Data,
    modelnData: modelnData
});
```

> **NOTE :**
>
> I would suggest to use Promise.all() if the queries are not dependent
>   on each other , as it will start execution and don't wait for the
>   first one to complete as it does in async/await.
>
> For More Deatil : **[DO READ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45286517/2349407)**

Comment: The first way works well with my, but the second one gives me the following error: SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: Yes you have to put async before function your_func_name(), please. See any async await function you will get idea ,