# Why does Promises.all doesn't work in my vuex store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, es6-promise, vuex-modules

I'm facing a weird issue right now. I have a vuex store in my vue project which is seperated in different modules. I want to use `Promise.all()` to execute two independent async vuex action at once to enjoy the advantage of the [first fail behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all#Promise.all_fail-fast_behaviour).

**store/modules/categories:**

```
    async CATEGORIES({ rootState }) {
        const response = await axios.post('link_to_api', {
            // some arguments for the api
            arg: rootState.args
        })

        return response
    }
```

**store/modules/transportation:**

```
    async TRANSPORTATION({ rootState }) {
         const response = await axios.post('link_to_api', {
            // some arguments for the api
            arg: rootState.args
        })

        return response
    }
```

I know want to call those async functions in `Promise.all`:

**store/modules/categories:**

```
    async PUT_CATEGORIES({ commit, dispatch, rootState }) {
      try {
         const [resCategories, resTransportation] = await Promise.all([
            dispatch('CATEGORIES').catch(err => { console.log('Fehler bei Kabinenabfrage!'); throw {error: err, origin: 'kabine'}; }),
            dispatch('transportation/TRANSPORTATION', {root:true}).catch(err => { console.log('Fehler bei Flugabfrage!'); throw {error: err, origin: 'flug'}; })
        ]) 
         //do something after both promises resolved

      } catch(error) {
            // do something if one promise rejected
            commit('errorlog/ERROR', 4, {root:true})
            dispatch("errorlog/LOG_ERROR", {'origin': '2', 'error_code': '113', 'message': error.toString()}, {root:true})
            router.push({path: '/Error'})
        }
```

I get the following error:

[image: error message]

This is weird because I used `{root:true}` and the prefix *transport* in dispatch to access the action of the transport module in store. This works great for the *LOG_ERROR* action in the *errorlog* module I use in the catch block.

If I copy the *TRANSPORTATION* action in the categories module it works great...

Has anybody faced this issue before and has an advice??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's weird to mix `await` with `.catch` but also `try/catch`

Comment: does `dispatch` return a Promise? or does it return `undefined` as suggested by the error? *`cannot read property 'catch' of undefined`*

Comment: Error is nowhere related to `Promise.all`

Comment: It should return a promise but it seems that it doesn't get the connection to the *TRANSPORT* action in the other modules and therefore it's `undefined` @Jaromanda X

Comment: very odd for something to return a Promise under some conditions and not others

Comment: Could you explain wy this is weird @VLAZ? I followed the answer of @mikep in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45285129/any-difference-between-await-promise-all-and-multiple-await).

Comment: shouldn't `dispatch('transportation/TRANSPORTATION'` be `dispatch('TRANSPORTATION'` as the error says there's no action specified with the provided namespace?

Comment: I tried that and the error message said `[vuex] unknown local action type: TRANSPORTATION, global type: categories/TRANSPORTATION`

Comment: It is (as already stated) not a problem of ```Promise.all```. The problem is your dispatch which returns undefined because your action is not found. In your post you say prefix ```transport``` but write ```transportation```. What is the namespace name in your store module definition? Also ```{root:true}``` should be third argument, not the second, pass ```null``` if need be as the second argument and do not prefix if you use ```root```

Comment: Thanks a lot @grodzi!! Passing `null` as second and then `{root:true}` as third argument did the trick. It works now :D You want to write this as answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, `{root:true}` is passed as second argument although it should be passed as third.

```
- dispatch('transportation/TRANSPORTATION', {root:true})
+ dispatch('transportation/TRANSPORTATION', null, {root:true})
```

According to [vuex's doc](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html)

> To dispatch actions or commit mutations in the global namespace, pass { root: true } as the 3rd argument to dispatch and commit.

They also provide a sample code (which is further simplified here)

```
modules: {
  foo: {
    namespaced: true,
    actions: {
      // dispatch and commit are also localized for this module
      // they will accept `root` option for the root dispatch/commit
      someAction ({ dispatch, commit, getters, rootGetters }) {
        dispatch('someOtherAction') // -> 'foo/someOtherAction'
        dispatch('someOtherAction', null, { root: true }) // -> 'someOtherAction'
```