# Promise rejection regardless of configuring catch clause on caller

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

In the context of this article : [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).  In section "Examples"

```
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  console.log("starting slow promise")
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve("slow")
      console.log("slow promise is done")
    }, 2000)
  })
}

function resolveAfter1Second() {
  console.log("starting fast promise")
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve("fast")
      console.log("fast promise is done")
    }, 1000)
  })
}

async function concurrentStart() {
  console.log('==CONCURRENT START with await==');
  const slow = resolveAfter2Seconds() // starts timer immediately
  const fast = resolveAfter1Second() // starts timer immediately

  // 1. Execution gets here almost instantly
  console.log(await slow) // 2. this runs 2 seconds after 1.
  console.log(await fast) // 3. this runs 2 seconds after 1., immediately after 2., since fast is already resolved
}
```

It says : In concurrentStart, if promise fast rejects before promise slow is fulfilled, then an unhandled promise rejection error will be raised, ***regardless of whether the caller has configured a catch clause***.

I didn't get that so i did little google and found this code snippet :

```
async function f() {
  let response = await fetch('http://no-such-url');
}

// f() becomes a rejected promise
f().catch(alert); // TypeError: failed to fetch // (*)
```

The above code works, it has a catch clause configured to caller.

So i am not getting why on promise rejection we will get error ??

Only observation i can make is that when promise corresponding to resolveAfter1Second()  will rejected the execution of function concurrentPromise is halted by awaiting on Promise of resolveAfter2Seconds().
But i am unable to connect dots between this observation and above statement made in article.

Comment: You haven't actually quoted the `concurrentStart` function from the linked article, which is the one referred to. As you observed, and as also stated in that note, `concurrentPromise` allows errors to be caught.

Comment: Edited the question. Thanks

Comment: Well your working example doesn't resemble `concurrentStart` in any significant way. There `f` returns a promise and therefore, if that promise is rejected, it can be handled by a `catch` method on `f() `. Although `concurrentStart` also returns a promise, it's not directly related to `slow` and `fast`, so if they reject, you can't handle them. The note was contrasting this with returning `Promise.all` called with the array of promises, which by design rejects whenever (and as soon as) any of the individual promises reject.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is explained better and in greater detail in [Waiting for more than one concurrent await operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46889290/waiting-for-more-than-one-concurrent-await-operation) and [Any difference between await Promise.all() and multiple await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45285129/any-difference-between-await-promise-all-and-multiple-await).

The MDN article does a bad job here. What the warning refers to is what happens when the two called functions return promises that will reject. The proper example code for that scenario is

```js
function rejectAfter2Seconds() {
  console.log("creating slow promise")
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      reject("slow error")
      console.log("slow promise is broken")
    }, 2000)
  })
}

function rejectAfter1Second() {
  console.log("creating fast promise")
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      reject("fast error")
      console.log("fast promise is broken")
    }, 1000)
  })
}

async function concurrentStart() {
  console.log('==CONCURRENT START with await==');
  const slow = rejectAfter2Seconds() // starts timer immediately
  const fast = rejectAfter1Second() // starts timer immediately

  console.log(await slow) // waits two seconds
  console.log(await fast) // causes unhandled rejection after one second
}
concurrentStart().catch(err => {
//               ^^^^^^ we can attach an error handler to the promise, but
  console.log(err); // it handles only one error
});
window.onunhandledrejection = err => {
  console.error(err.reason); // and we still get an unhandled rejection
};
```