# Resolve promises in object tree

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

1. How do I resolve `foo3`
2. How can I resolve the object tree without `async/await` with only plain `Promise` (without depending on `regenerator-runtime`)

```js
const p = v => {
  return new Promise(resolve => 
    setTimeout(resolve.bind(null, v), 2000)
  )
}

const tree = {
  element: p('foo'),
  children: [
    p({
      element: 'bar',
      children: null
    }),
    p({
      element: 'bar2',
      children: [
        {
          element: p('foo3'),
          children: null
        }
      ]
    })
  ]
}

const fullfill = async vtree => {
  if(vtree instanceof Promise) {
    await vtree
  } else if(Array.isArray(vtree)) {
    await Promise.all(vtree.map(fullfill))
  } else if(typeof vtree !== 'object') {
    return vtree
  } else {
    let { element, children = [] } = vtree
    if(element instanceof Promise) {
      element = await element
    }
    if(children.length) {
      children = await Promise.all(children.map(fullfill))
    }
    return {
      element,
      children
    }
  }
  return vtree
}

fullfill(tree).then(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's hardly a reason to use `async`/`await` if all you're doing is to `return` the result anyway. You'd only use it for the tree node (element+children) case, but there you can easily do the transformation after [the necessary `Promise.all`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45285129/any-difference-between-await-promise-all-and-multiple-await) with `then` as well:

```
function treeAll(vtree) {
  if (typeof vtree !== 'object' || vtree == null) {
    return Promise.resolve(vtree);
  } else if (vtree instanceof Promise) {
    return vtree.then(treeAll);
  } else if (Array.isArray(vtree)) {
    return Promise.all(vtree.map(treeAll));
  } else {
    return Promise.all([
      vtree.element,
      treeAll(vtree.children)
    ]).then(([element, children]) => ({
      element,
      children
    }));
  }
}
```

Comment: This quite close on how to solve the tree now only ``foo3`` not resolve, but some fixing might nail this

Comment: @syarul Done. It was missing either the `vtree.then(treeAll)` on child nodes that are a promise, or doing `Promise.all(vtree).then(arr => arr.map(treeAll))` on arrays instead of `Promise.all(vtree.map(treeAll))`

Answer (score 1):

Problem with your code was your `children` value of `tree` object was processed by first `if (vtree instanceof Promise) {`. And their child never processed.

To properly process child I removed assigned assign awaited object back to `vtree` inside first `if` (Change 1) & add `vtree = await fullfill(vtree)` next to it (Change 2).

Use children && children.length so if children is null then it won't throw exception. (Change 3)

Test it below.

```js
const p = v => {
  return new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(resolve.bind(null, v), 2000)
  )
}

const tree = {
  element: p('foo'),
  children: [
    p({
      element: 'bar',
      children: null
    }),
    p({
      element: 'bar2',
      children: [{
        element: p('foo3'),
        children: null
      }]
    })
  ]
}

const fullfill = async vtree => {

  if (vtree instanceof Promise) {
    // Chanage 1
    // assign awaited object back to vtree
    vtree = await vtree;
    // Chanage 2
    // Call fullfill and pass vtree
    vtree = await fullfill(vtree);
  } else if (Array.isArray(vtree)) {
    await Promise.all(vtree.map(fullfill))
  } else if (typeof vtree !== 'object') {
    return vtree
  } else {
    let {
      element,
      children = []
    } = vtree
    if (element instanceof Promise) {
      element = await element
    }
    // Chanage 3
    // use children && children.length so if children is null then it won't throw exception.
    if (children && children.length) {
      children = await Promise.all(children.map(fullfill));
    }
    return {
      element,
      children
    }
  }
  return vtree
}

fullfill(tree).then(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
```

---

**Edit** without `await`. To remove `await` we need to `return Promise`. Please review first code snippet and then check equivalent version in second snippet which `return Promise` instead of `await`.

Test it below.

```js
const p = v => {
  return new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(resolve.bind(null, v), 2000)
  )
}

const tree = {
  element: p('foo'),
  children: [
    p({
      element: 'bar',
      children: null
    }),
    p({
      element: 'bar2',
      children: [{
        element: p('foo3'),
        children: null
      }]
    })
  ]
}

const fullfill = async vtree => {

  if (vtree instanceof Promise) {
    // Chanage 1
    // assign awaited object back to vtree
    return vtree.then(r => fullfill(r))
    //vtree = await vtree;
    //vtree = await fullfill(vtree);
  }

  // Chanage 2
  // update else if condition to if here.
  else if (Array.isArray(vtree)) {
    return Promise.all(vtree.map(fullfill))
  } else if (typeof vtree !== 'object') {
    return vtree
  } else {
    let {
      element,
      children = []
    } = vtree
    if (element instanceof Promise) {
      // element = await element
      return element.then(e => {
        if (children && children.length) {
          return Promise.all(children.map(fullfill)).then(c => ({
            element: e,
            children: c
          }));
        };
        return {
          element: e,
          children: children
        };
      });
    }
    // Chanage 3
    // use children && children.length so if children is null then it won't throw exception.
    else if (children && children.length) {
      return Promise.all(children.map(fullfill)).then(c => ({
        element: element,
        children: c
      }));
    }
  }
  return vtree
}

fullfill(tree).then(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Updated my answer. Check second snippet for your point 2.