# Make for loop asynchronous in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, ecmascript-6

I have a function that consists of a for a loop. Loop runs for a certain time and after that returns a value. my only aim is to return the value, once the loop runs entirely. I tried with **Promise** and **Async-Await** but none of them work for me.

Async Function

```js
async function getTotalQuestion(tag, question) {
    var output = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < question; i++) {
        getOne(tag).then((data) => {
                output.push(data);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);

            })
    }
    return output;
}
```

calling of the async function

```
getTotalQuestion('eco', 9).then((data) => {
        question = data; //here data is coming as undefined
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
```

Comment: You must make the function inside the for loop to wait. Something like await getOne(tag)...

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in the above code is that it does not wait for `getOne` to push `data` into the `output` array. In order to get the correct `output`, you'll have to await the result of `getOne` inside the `for` loop.

```js
async function getTotalQuestion(tag, question) {
    var output = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < question; i++) {
        try {
            var data = await getOne(tag);
            output.push(data);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Yeah. The way I like to think about it is, imagine that `getOne` takes a long time, like 30 seconds to give you a result. In the original code, when `i === 0` it'll start that 30 second process but not wait for it to finish and instead proceed to `i === 1`, etc. etc.

Comment: thanks, @kunal. it works. just one doubt, getOne is already a promise, promise itself an async method. it has to wait isn't it

Comment: @Pranaykumar Promise is a value that might resolve or reject in the future (with the stress on the future). Therefore, whenever a function returns a Promise, it might return a value (resolve) or throw an error (reject) but after it has completed processing. Now, in order to use the function's return value, one must explicitly wait (using `await` or `then`) for the it to finish it's task(s) and provide the required output.

Answer (score 0):

If each `getOne()` call is independent of the other and can be called in any sequence, then you can use `Promise.all()` to asynchronously call multiple `getOne()` calls. Then await for all of them to complete before returning the total result from `getTotalQuestion()`.

```js
async function getTotalQuestion(tag, question) {
    try {
        return await Promise.all(Array(question).fill(0).map(_ => getOne(tag)));
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

If the order of calls to `getOne()` matter, then obviously the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66300092/11057988) posted works and you should await for each call in a for loop. Read more about [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). And learn more about the difference between `Promise.all()` and multiple `await` calls in this [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45285129/11057988).