# Rejected Promise breaks loop despite catch

Tags: node.js, loops, promise, catch-block

I am creating a loop to create/update users using functions with built-in promises:

```
for (const user of usersjson.users) {
 let getuser = getUser(url, okapikey, user[fieldMap.externalSystemId], 
 'externalSystemId'); //Check if user exists on the server
 await getuser
  .then(async (data) => {
    if (data.users.length != 0) { //If user exists in the array
      update = updateUser(url, okapikey, createduser, data.users[0].id);//Create update function
      promises.push(update); //Store function in array
      i++;
    } else {
      create = createNewUser(url, okapikey, createduser);//Create create function 
      promises.push(create); //Store function in array
      i++;
    }
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });
  if (promises.length == 50 || i == usersjson.users.length) {//Run functions in batches of 50
     await Promise.allSettled(promises)
     .then((responses)=> {
       for (const response of responses) { //For each promise response
         if (response.status == 'fulfilled') { //If fulfilled
           if (response.value.status == 204) {
             console.log(`${response.value.status}: User ${response.value.request.path.substring(7)} was updated.`);
           } else {
             if (response.value.status == 201 && response.value.headers.location) {
               console.log(`${response.value.status}: User ${response.value.headers['location']} was created.`);
             } else {
               console.log(response.value.headers.location);
             }
           }
         } else { //Handle rejections
           console.log(`There was an error with the user:${response.value}`);
         }
       }
     }).catch((err)=> {
       console.log(err);
     });
     promises=[]; //Empty Promise array 
   }
}

async function updateUser(url, token, user, userid)
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //Create headers for put request
        const options = {
            method: "put",
            headers: {
            'x-okapi-token': token,
            'x-okapi-tenant':'tenant',
            'Content-type':"application/json"
            }
        };
        //Make API get call
        user.id=userid; //Adding the required field ID to the JSON
        axios.put(`${url}/users/${userid}`, JSON.stringify(user), options)
            .then(response => {
              if (response.status == 204) {
                resolve(response);
              } else {
                reject(`Error Code: ${err.response.status}\nError Text: ${err.response.data.errors[0].message}\nError Status: ${err}`);
              }
            }).catch((err) => {
            console.error(`Error Code: ${err.response.status}`);
            if (typeof err.response.data == 'string') {
                console.error(err.response.data);
                reject(`Error Code: ${err.response.status}\nError Text: ${err.response.data.errors[0].message}\nError Status: ${err}`);
            } else if (err.response.data.errors[0].message) {
                console.error(`Error Text: ${err.response.data.errors[0].message}`);
                reject(`Error Code: ${err.response.status}\nError Text: ${err.response.data.errors[0].message}\nError Status: ${err}`);
            } else {
              reject(`Error Code: ${err.response.status}\nError Text: ${err.response.data.errors[0].message}\nError Status: ${err}`);
            }
            console.log(err.response);
            });
    });
};

async function createNewUser (url, token, user) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //Create headers for put request
        const options = {
            headers: {
            'X-Okapi-token': token,
            'Content-type':"application/json"
            }
        };
        //Make API get call
        axios.post(`${url}/users`, JSON.stringify(user), options)
            .then(response => {
            if (response.status == 201) {
              resolve(response);
            } else {
              reject(`Error Code: ${err.response.status}: ${user.externalSystemId},\nError Text: ${err.response.data.errors[0].message},\nError Status: ${err}`)
            }
            }).catch((err) => {
            console.error(`Error on ${user.externalSystemId}: ${err}`);
            if (err.response.data && typeof err.response.data == 'string') {
                console.error(err.response.data);
                reject(`Error Code: ${err.response.status}: ${user.externalSystemId},\nError Text: ${err.response.data.errors[0].message},\nError Status: ${err}`)
            } else if (err.response.data.errors[0].message) {
                console.error(`Error Text: ${err.response.data.errors[0].message}`);
                reject(`Error Code: ${err.response.status}: ${user.externalSystemId},\nError Text: ${err.response.data.errors[0].message},\nError Status: ${err}`)
            } else {
              reject(`Error Code: ${err.response.status}: ${user.externalSystemId},\nError Text: ${err.response.data.errors[0].message},\nError Status: ${err}`)
            }
            });
    });
};

const getUsers = (url,user,password) =>
{
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  //Create headers for POST request
  const options = {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
       'Authorization': 'Basic '+Buffer.from(`${user}:${password}`).toString('base64')
    }
  }
  //Make API get call
  axios.get(url, options)
    .then(response => {
      resolve(response.data);
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      reject(err);
    });
});
};
```

The code and loop works fine when every promise is fulfilled, but once a promise is rejected, the loop breaks. I get the error message, for example:

> Error on XXX: Error: Request failed with status code 422 Error Text:
> User with this username already exists
> node:internal/process/promises:246
> triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
> ^
>
> [UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing
> inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a
> promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with
> the reason "Error Code: 422: XXX, Error Text: User with this username
> already exists, Error Status: Error: Request failed with status code
> 422".] { }

Looking at the code and error, I believe this comes from the "createNewUser" function.
I'm not sure why the code breaks - I added catches to all the functions, handled rejections, and added catch statements in the main body of the code, but the loop still breaks.

What I need is for the loop to continue as usual even if one function fails (I will later change the log from console.log to an actual log file).

Comment: Btw, avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it) in your `updateUser`/`createNewUser`/`getUsers` functions!

Comment: you misuse/misunderstand `await`. `let getUser = getUser(...); await getUser.then(data => ...)` is the same as `let data = await getUser(...); ...` try not to mix `await` with `.then` in situations like this

Comment: @Bergi Since you helped here and the code I implemented was your suggested changes, I thought maybe you could help with a strange issue caused by it.
It didn't happen in the previous version, only once I changed the array to functions as you showed me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67677866/repeating-values-passed-to-function-in-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> update = updateUser(url, okapikey, createduser, data.users[0].id);//Create update function
> promises.push(update); //Store function in array
>
> create = createNewUser(url, okapikey, createduser);//Create create function 
> promises.push(create); //Store function in array
> ```

This is inaccurate. You are not storing *functions* in that array, you actually call the `updateUser`/`createNewUser` functions here and store the resulting promises in the array. Then, your loop goes on to sequentially (because of the `await`) do more `getUser` operations before actually calling `Promise.allSettled` on the `promises` array. In the meantime, some of the promises might already have been rejected without having any handlers attached to them.

This is basically the same problem as discussed in [Waiting for more than one concurrent await operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46889290/waiting-for-more-than-one-concurrent-await-operation) and [Any difference between await Promise.all() and multiple await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45285129/any-difference-between-await-promise-all-and-multiple-await).

To fix it, collect actual functions that you can execute later in your array:

```
let functions = [];
for (const user of usersjson.users) {
  i++;
  try {
    const data = await getUser(url, okapikey, user[fieldMap.externalSystemId], 'externalSystemId');
    if (data.users.length != 0) {
      functions.push(() =>
//                   ^^^^^
        updateUser(url, okapikey, createduser, data.users[0].id)
      ); // Create update function and store it in array
    } else {
      functions.push(() =>
//                   ^^^^^
        createNewUser(url, okapikey, createduser)
      ); // Create create function and store it in array
    }
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
  if (functions.length == 50 || i == usersjson.users.length) { // in batches of 50
    const promises = functions.map(fn => fn()); // Run functions
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    const responses = await Promise.allSettled(promises);
    for (const response of responses) {
      if (response.status == 'fulfilled') {
        if (response.value.status == 204) {
          console.log(`${response.value.status}: User ${response.value.request.path.substring(7)} was updated.`);
        } else {
          if (response.value.status == 201 && response.value.headers.location) {
            console.log(`${response.value.status}: User ${response.value.headers['location']} was created.`);
          } else {
            console.log(response.value.headers.location);
          }
        }
      } else {
        console.log(`There was an error with the user:${response.value}`);
      }
    }
    functions = []; // empty functions array 
  }
}
```

(I've tried to [avoid `await`ing any `.then(…)` chains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54387912/1048572))

Comment: Thanks! I'll try and do that right now and see if it works!
But before I do, I am a bit confused at your comment about Promise constructor antipatterns. I looked at the answers in the thread you posted but the promises there are much simpler than mine and I can't figure out what is wrong with my functions. I seem to have a reject for every situation or error.

Comment: @NimrodYanai While you seem to have handled all cases correctly (always calling either `resolve` or `reject`), you can simplify them a lot by just using `return` and `throw` in the `then`/`catch` handlers, without any `new Promise`.

Comment: Well, I don't know why, but this caused the functions to stop working.
I made the changes as you suggested, and now the update function breaks even though I never touched it.
The good news is - the code indeed continues to run even though some of the promises are rejected, so I'm going to call this one solved!
Thanks!