# Promise.all vs [await x, await y] - Is it really the same?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

This is a basic question, but i couldn't find the answer to it anywhere.

We have two approaches:

```js
// consider someFunction1() and someFunction2() as functions that returns Promises

Approach #1:
return [await someFunction1(), await someFunction2()]

Approach #2:
return await Promise.all([someFunction1(), someFunction2()])
```

My Team Leader said that both approaches ended up in the same solution (both functions executting in parallel). But, from my knowledge, the first approach would `await someFunction1()` to resolve and then would execute someFunction2.

So that's the question, is it really the same, or are there any performance improvements on second approach? Proofs are very welcome!

Comment: "*My Team Leader said that both approaches ended up in the same solution (both functions executting in parallel).*" that is incorrect "*But, from my knowledge, the first approach would await someFunction1() to resolve and then would execute someFunction2.*" that is correct.

Comment: ^^ What they said! They are absolutely not the same thing. Easy enough to demonstrate - would you like me to?

Comment: If you don't mind, i would like it. Would be good, so i can use it as example to show him.

Comment: `const promise1 = someFunction1(), promise2 = someFunction2();` and then `return [await promise1, await promise2];` this would be comparable to `Promise.all()`. Here, the first `await` only defers/delays the "then"-part of the second promise, not it's creation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you should not accept that:

```
return [await someFunction1(), await someFunction2()];
```

Is the same as:

```
return await Promise.all([someFunction1(), someFunction2()]);
```

<sup>I should also note that `await` in the above `return await` is not needed. Check out [this blog post](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/await-vs-return-vs-return-await/) to learn more.</sup>

They are **different**!

---

## The first approach (sequential)

Let's determine the difference by inspecting how each of the two alternatives works.

```
[await someFunction1(), await someFunction2()];
```

Here, in an `async` context, we create an array literal. Note that `someFunction1` is called (a function which probably returns a new promise each time it gets called).

So, when you call `someFunction1`, a new promise is returned, which then "locks" the `async` context because the preceding `await`.

In a nutshell, the `await someFunction1()` "blocks" the array initialization until the returned promise gets settled (by getting resolved or rejected).

The same process is repeated to `someFunction2`.

Note that, in this first approach, the two promises are awaited in sequence. There is, therefore, no similarity with the approach that uses `Promise.all`. Let's see why.

## The second approach (*non-sequential*)

```
Promise.all([someFunction1(), someFunction2()])
```

When you apply `Promise.all`, it expects an iterable of promises. It waits for **all** the promises you give to resolve before returns a new array of resolved values, but don't wait each promise resolve until waiting another one. In essence, it awaits all the promises at the same time, so it is a kind of "non-sequential". As JavaScript is single-threaded, you cannot tell this "parallel", but is very similar in the behavior point of view.

So, when you pass this array:

```
[someFunction1(), someFunction2()]
```

You are actually passing an array of promises (which are returned from the functions). Something like:

```
[Promise<...>, Promise<...>]
```

Note that the promises are being created **outside** `Promise.all`.

So you are, in fact, passing an array of promises to `Promise.all`. When both of them gets resolved, the `Promise.all` returns the array of resolved values. I won't explain in all details how `Promise.all` works, for that, I suggest you checking out the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

You can replicate this "non-sequential" approach by creating the promises **before** using the `await`. Like so:

```
const promise1 = someFunction1();
const promise2 = someFunction2();
return [await promise1, await promise2];
```

While `promise1` is being waited, `promise2` is already running (as it was created before the first `await`), so the behavior is similar to `Promise.all`'s.

Comment: `return [await promise1, await promise2];` is *not* the same as `Approach2`. It's *similar* but only if the promises resolve successfully. It can lead to uncaught promise rejections if one fails. https://jsbin.com/pojumujoqe/1/edit?js,console,output EDIT: see also [Any difference between await Promise.all() and multiple await?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45285129)

Comment: I think this was just a misunderstanding, he tried to say `No, you should not accept that <using list await> is the same as <using Promise.all>`

Comment: @VLAZ, I said: "You can replicate this "non-sequential" approach [...]", **not** "You can replicate the `Promise.all` behavior [...]". I am well aware of the differences, but I don't think they enter in the scope of the question. I might edit it later to make this more clear, though. Thanks for the heads up, nonetheless. :) Another difference, of course, is that `[await p1, await p2]` does not short circuit, unlike `Promise.all([p1, p2])` but, again, I don't think this is about what the question asks.

Comment: Check a complete guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45285129/any-difference-between-await-promise-all-and-multiple-await

Answer (score 5):

> My Team Leader said that both approaches ended up in the same solution (both functions executting in parallel).

That is incorrect.

> But, from my knowledge, the first approach would `await someFunction1()` to resolve and then would execute someFunction2.

That is correct.

Here is a demonstration

#### Approach 1:

```js
const delay = (ms, value) =>
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms, value));
  
async function Approach1() {
  return [await someFunction1(), await someFunction2()];
}
  
async function someFunction1() {
  const result = await delay(800, "hello");
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}

async function someFunction2() {
  const result = await delay(400, "world");
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}

async function main() {
  const start = new Date();
  const result = await Approach1();
  const totalTime = new Date() - start;
  console.log(`result: ${result}
    total time: ${totalTime}`);
}

main();
```

Result is:

```
hello
world
result: hello,world
    total time: 1205
```

Which means that `someFunction1` runs to completion *first* and then `someFunction2` is executed. It is sequential

#### Approach 2:

```js
const delay = (ms, value) =>
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms, value));
  
async function Approach2() {
  return await Promise.all([someFunction1(), someFunction2()]);
}
  
async function someFunction1() {
  const result = await delay(800, "hello");
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}

async function someFunction2() {
  const result = await delay(400, "world");
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}

async function main() {
  const start = new Date();
  const result = await Approach2();
  const totalTime = new Date() - start;
  console.log(`result: ${result}
    total time: ${totalTime}`);
}

main();
```

Result is:

```
world
hello
result: hello,world
    total time: 803
```

Which means that `someFunction2` finishes *before* `someFunction1`. The two are parallel.

Comment: Best answer so far, but could  you please remove this `async`/`await` in `Approach2`? It's not needed at all (you can compare it to your `delay` function).

Comment: @ulou I used the code from OP. I prefer code to be representative to a question, even if redundant. Makes it easy to correlate it to the information in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Easy to see the difference

```js
    function createTimer(ms, id) {
      console.log(`id: ${id} started ${new Date()}`);
      return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        setTimeout( () => {
          console.log(`id: ${id} finished ${new Date()}`);
          res(id);      
        }, ms );
      });
    }

    (async function() {

      var result1 = [await createTimer(5000, '1'), await createTimer(5000, '2')];
      var result2 = await Promise.all([createTimer(5000, '3'), createTimer(5000, '4')]);

      console.log(result1);
      console.log(result2);

    })();
```

The first one starts `1` and when `1` finishes it starts `2`.
The second one starts `3` and `4` at almost the very same moment.

Answer (score 1):

[MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all#description) for `Promise.all()` states that

> This method can be useful for aggregating the results of multiple promises. It is typically used when there are multiple related asynchronous tasks that the overall code relies on to work successfully — **all of whom we want to fulfill before the code execution continues.**

While it isn't explicit, you can await `Promise.all` to track multiple promises. Only when all promises are resolved will the code execution continue.

The other approach you mention of capturing separate asynchronous tasks in an array is not the same due to how [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#description) operates.

> An await splits execution flow, allowing the caller of the async function to resume execution. After the await defers the continuation of the async function, execution of subsequent statements ensues. If this await is the last expression executed by its function, execution continues by returning to the function's caller a pending Promise for completion of the await's function and resuming execution of that caller.

So, each await will pause execution before resuming. No need for a demonstration.

Comment: "*While it isn't explicit, the intention is that Promise.all will run all the asynchronous tasks simultaneously*" this is misleading. `Promise.all` doesn't *run* tasks. Creating a promise will start a task. `Promise.all` will just wait for all of them to complete, at the point when you call `Promise.all` the task *is already running*. This is very important and very often misunderstood. Promises are only a notification mechanism for the state of an async operation (finished/failed/not yet ready). You don't "start" or "stop" an async task using the promise.

Comment: Adjusted for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

If you start with a function which simulates doing some work which outputs at stages of that work but takes some time. eg

```
function someFunction1(){
   return new Promise(resolve => {
       let i = 0;
       const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
          i++;
          console.log("someFunction1", i);
          if(i == 5){
            clearInterval(intervalId)
            resolve(1); 
          }
       }, 1000);
   });
}
```

And then you duplicate that with a second, similar, method. You plug your 2 methods in and you see that the one using `Promise.all` does it in parallel but the one using 2 `await` calls does it in series.

Parallel

```js
function someFunction1(){
   return new Promise(resolve => {
       let i = 0;
       const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
          i++;
          console.log("someFunction1", i);
          if(i == 5){
            clearInterval(intervalId)
            resolve(1); 
          }
       }, 1000);
   });
}

function someFunction2(){
   return new Promise(resolve => {
       let i = 0;
       const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
          i++;
          console.log("someFunction2", i);
          if(i == 5){
            clearInterval(intervalId)
            resolve(2); 
          }
       }, 1000);
   });
}

(async function(){
   const result = await Promise.all([someFunction1(),someFunction2()]);
   console.log("result",result);
})();
```

Series

```js
function someFunction1(){
   return new Promise(resolve => {
       let i = 0;
       const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
          i++;
          console.log("someFunction1", i);
          if(i == 5){
            clearInterval(intervalId)
            resolve(1); 
          }
       }, 1000);
   });
}

function someFunction2(){
   return new Promise(resolve => {
       let i = 0;
       const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
          i++;
          console.log("someFunction2", i);
          if(i == 5){
            clearInterval(intervalId)
            resolve(2); 
          }
       }, 1000);
   });
}

(async function(){
   const result = [await someFunction1(),await someFunction2()];
   console.log("result",result);
})();
```

Both give the exact same *result* but getting there is very different.