# JavaScript: weird bug when using Promises to load images in order

Tags: javascript, html, es6-promise

I have an array of image urls and I want to display these images on the webpage in the order of the placement of their corresponding URL in the array.

for example, we have

```js
const imgUrls = [
  "https://picsum.photos/400/400",
  "https://picsum.photos/200/200",
  "https://picsum.photos/300/300"
];
```

in which case we want to display `400/400` first, then `200/200` and lastly `300/300`.

If we implement it naively then the order is not guaranteed.

```js
function loadImages(imgUrls, root) {
  imgUrls.forEach((url) => {
    const image = document.createElement("img");
    image.onload = () => {
      root.append(image);
    };
    image.src = url;
  });
}
```

So I use Promises to manage the async flow control

```js
async function loadImagesInOrder(imgUrls, rootEl) {
  const promises = imgUrls.map(
    (url) =>
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const image = document.createElement("img");
        image.onload = resolve;
        image.onerror = reject;
        image.src = url;
      })
  );

  for (const p of promises) {
    const { currentTarget } = await p;
    rootEl.append(currentTarget);
  }
}
```

It works, but not all of the time. With this implementation, Sometimes some images are going to be `null` so you end up with `null` on the webpage.

This is the live demo
https://codesandbox.io/s/load-images-in-order-t16hs?file=/src/index.js

Can someone point out what the problem is? Also **is there any better way to make sure** the image appear on the page in the order of the URL in the array?

Comment: `Note: The value of event.currentTarget is only available while the event is being handled`

Comment: so I guess the problem is that sometimes the event is not handled? why is that?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46889290/waiting-for-more-than-one-concurrent-await-operation) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45285129/any-difference-between-await-promise-all-and-multiple-await) for why you should not `await` promises in a loop that you constructed before it.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the `.currentTarget` of the event is sometimes `null` for some reason. An easy fix is to resolve the Promise with the image itself, instead of going through the problematic `load` handler. Keith found why in the comments:

> Note: The value of event.currentTarget is only available while the event is being handled

But when you do

```
  for (const p of promises) {
    const { currentTarget } = await p;
    rootEl.append(currentTarget);
  }
```

All of the images have their loading process initiated *immediately*, but they load asynchronously, and they often don't load in order. The `.currentTarget` will not exist if the Promise resolves after image has already loaded - for example, if image 1, then image 3 loads, then image 2 loads, image 3 will have already been loaded by the time the third image's

```
const { currentTarget } = await p;
```

runs.

If you simply need to order the images properly in the end, an easier approach would be to append them immediately.

```js
const root = document.querySelector("#app");

const imgUrls = [
  "https://picsum.photos/400/400",
  "https://picsum.photos/200/200",
  "https://picsum.photos/300/300"
];

for (const src of imgUrls) {
  root.appendChild(document.createElement('img')).src = src;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wonder what the differences between the `root.appendChild(document.createElement('img')).src = src;` approach vs. my original approach? I think the difference is that, my approach only shows the images  once they are fully loaded while your approach lets the browser show the image right after it kicks out the Get request so there might be some intermediate stage of loading -  the image could visually load in chunks.

Comment: Yep, if you wanted to only show them once they're fully loaded, I'd recommend changing the style from display:none after the load event fires. If you want to display them all at once when all images are loaded, hide the container, and after a `Promise.all` on the `load` events, show the container.

Comment: yea I was thinking before the image fully loads we show some sort of placeholder by giving it a background image style and once it fully loads we swap them by removing that style... btw didn't `appendChild` would return the child being appended, good to know!

Comment: Hi could you expound on this a little bit more "The .currentTarget will not exist if the Promise resolves after image has already loaded "? I am not sure if I understand it...