# What's the best way to handle a list of promises in an isolated manner?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, event-loop, deno

I've been giving some thought at what could be the best way to deal with a batch of heavy operations with Javascript and I came up with the following:

```js
const results: Promise<void>[] = [];

// Start all pieces of work concurrently
for (const record of await getData()) {
  results.push(doSomeHeavyWork(records));
}

// Collect the results
for (const result of results) {
  // Isolate the failures so one doesn't break another.
  try {
    await result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
}
```

My understanding is that the above snippet takes as long as the longest operation, and that's as good as it's going to get AFAIK. However, is there a better or more idiomatic way of going about this problem?

I'm not really looking necessarily at node here. This could be node, Deno or browser code.

Comment: In browser code you can use `setTimeout(myTimeConsumingFunction, 0)` which will run the function in  a separate browser thread.

Comment: The event loop doesn't *make* anything concurrent. What does `doSomeHeavyWork` do? Is it actually asynchronous work?

Comment: Assuming `doSomeHeavyWork` returns a promise that sometimes rejects, this code is actually broken and as it may lead to unhandled promise rejections crashing your process. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46889290/waiting-for-more-than-one-concurrent-await-operation) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45285129/any-difference-between-await-promise-all-and-multiple-await). Use `Promise.all` instead!

Comment: I suppose you could implement Web Workers..they run without interfering with the UI thread. 

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: Is the doSomeHeavyWork doing a lot of IO? If so use promises makes sense. If you are actually doing a lot of CPU work then what you are doing won't help because everything is still running the same the thread. Instead you need to look at using worker threads.

Comment: It's also important to distinguish between the reasons for long-running async promises (e.g. computationally-expensive tasks vs ones which depend on an inexpensive, but latent result like receiving a network response).

Comment: Thanks all for the valuable feedback! First off, let's assume `dosomeHeavyWork` does some IO and some CPU, mostly IO. Second off, I understand the benefits of `Promise.all`, but the main point is that I want to wait for *all* the tasks to finish, and handle each resolution/rejection separately. That's the usecase I want to focus on. How would you go about it?

Comment: @Bergi I totally get your point, but `Promise.all` doesn't cut it for me. What would other alternatives be?

Comment: @JavierGarcíaManzano `Promise.all(data.map(record => doSomeHeavyWork(records).catch(…))` *does* cut it for you. Or use `Promise.allSettled` if you don't want to get error logs early.

Comment: @Bergi aha, gotcha. I just realised. So the trick here is to actually add a `catch` call on the promises so they don't "blow up". Am I right to understand that by adding that `catch` call the call to `Promise.all` then waits for all of the results? Assuming that `Promise.allSettled` gets me to the same place, it does feel like it expresses the intent better.

Comment: @JavierGarcíaManzano Doing `Promise.all(data.map(doSomeHeavyWork)).catch(…)` waits for all the results, but fails altogether if any one fails. If you put `.catch()` on each `doSomeHeavyWork` call individually, it will also wait for all the results, but result in `undefined` (or whatever your `catch` callback returned) for those that failed. `Promise.allSettled` will also wait for all the results, but let you handle (or log) errors only once everything has finished, not as soon as the error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, just pushing the promises inside the array won't start a concurrency work, but the way you will resolve them that can be made in a concurrency way. In this `for` loop, each item of the `results` array will execute synchronously one after another without any concurrency execution and the performance will be very low.

The javascript provides a way to achieve this "concurrency" execution, using the [all](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) static method of the `Promise` native class:

```
const results: Promise<void>[] = [];

// Start all pieces of work concurrently
for (const record of await getData()) {
  results.push(doSomeHeavyWork(records));
}

// Without handling errors will be just like this
await Promise.all(results);
```

In the above example, all promises will be resolved, but if one fails all of them will fail too (consider see more about [allSettled](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled), if this is not what you want). To handle each promise error, you can just attach a catch block to each promise inside the array:

```
const results: Promise<void>[] = [];

// Start all pieces of work concurrently
for (const record of await getData()) {
  results.push(doSomeHeavyWork(records));
}

// Handling errors will be just like this
await Promise.all(results.map(r => r.catch(error => console.log(JSON.stringify(error)))));
```

***Note:*** concurrency is underquoted because nodeJS is a monothread language, so this concurrency does not happen in different threads.

Comment: "*In this `for` loop, each item of the `results` array will execute synchronously one after another*" - no. As you mention, `results` is holding promises, so nothing does "execute" when you `await` them.

Comment: I mean the second `for` loop, where he is "awaiting" the `result` (item of the `results` array). I may have used wrong words to explain, but each promise will be awaited, and the loop just goes to the next promise when this has already been resolved or rejected. @Bergi

Comment: Yes, but there's no slowdow through that, "*performance will be very low*" is wrong. All the `doSomeHeavyWork` execution starts in the first loop already, there is no performance difference between `Promise.all`(`settled`) and the original code. Just a correctness one - `Promise.all` doesn't cause unhandled rejection crashes (and it's also simpler code).