# Async await with Fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

my fetch works perfectly with .then, but i want to step it up a notch by using `async` and `await`. It should wait for all 5 API calls, and then place the answer, instead, it shows answer on every API call

```js
async function getPhotosFromAPI() {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    let albums = await fetch(
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/?albumId=${i}`
    );
    let result = await albums.json();
    let res = `<div class="album${i}"></div>`;
    document.querySelector(".display-images").innerHTML += res;
    for (let j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
      document.querySelector(
        `.album${i}`
      ).innerHTML += `<img src="${result[j].url}"/>`;
    }
  }
  
  console.log(result);
}
async function showPhotos() {
  await getPhotosFromAPI();
  document.getElementById("#loader").style.display = "none";
}
showPhotos();
```

```js
document.getElementById("img").style.display = "block";
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/?albumId=${i}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => {
      document.getElementById("img").style.display = "none";

      const display = document.querySelector(".display-images");
      const albumNo = document.querySelector(".album-no");
      //   document.getElementById('img').style.display = "block";
      // document.getElementById('img').style.display = "none";]
      display.innerHTML += `<div class="album-${i}>`;
      for (let z = 1; z <= 5; z++) {
        display.innerHTML += `<img id="img" alt="pic-from-album${json[i].albumId}" src="${json[z].url}"/>`;
      }
      display.innerHTML += `<div>`;
    });
}
```

Comment: Have alook at the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45285129/any-difference-between-await-promise-all-and-multiple-await) - it will give you some insights how to work out multiple awaits..

Comment: Can u share your version with `.then` too? Looks like the issue is not related with async/await but the code itself

Comment: Show the .then code version. So we can tell you what you're doing wrong

Comment: @Bravo, i added the .then version

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: The code in your `async` function (the parts after the `fetch`!) is ostensibly very different from the one in your `then` handler. It's not clear why you expected them to have the same result?

Comment: @Bergi well im trying to xD

Answer (score 2):

You should use a concurrent way of fetching like Promise.all to avoid round-trips

```js
async function getPhotosFromAPI() {
  let albums = await Promise.all(
    Array(5).fill().map((elem, index) => 
      fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/?albumId=${index+1}`)
    )
  )
  let results = await Promise.all(
    albums.map(album => album.json())
  )
  console.log(results)
  return results
}

getPhotosFromAPI()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for the code to wait until each `fetch` finishes by using `await` on `fetch`'s return value (then again on the return value of `json`) in your loop. So it will do just that: wait until that request is complete before moving on to the next loop iteration.

If you don't want to do that, you need to start each `fetch` one after another and then wait for them all to complete. I'd probably break out the work for just one of them into a function, then call it five times, building an array of the promises it returns, then `await Promise.all(/*...*/)` those promises, something along these lines:

```
document.getElementById("img").style.display = "block";
// Fetch one item
const fetchOne = async (i) => {
    const response = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/?albumId=${i}`);
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
    }
    const data = await response.json();
    document.getElementById("img").style.display = "none";

    const display = document.querySelector(".display-images");
    const albumNo = document.querySelector(".album-no");
    //   document.getElementById('img').style.display = "block";
    // document.getElementById('img').style.display = "none";]
    display.innerHTML += `<div class="album-${i}>`;
    for (let z = 1; z <= 5; z++) {
        display.innerHTML += `<img id="img" alt="pic-from-album${data[i].albumId}" src="${data[z].url}"/>`;
    }
    display.innerHTML += `<div>`;
};
// ...
await Promise.all(Array.from({length: 5}, (_, i) => fetchOne(i + 1)));
// All done
```

(I took the version with `.then` as my starting point for the above, since the two versions in your question were so different and you said the one with `.then` worked... Also note that I renamed the variable `json` to `data`, since it doesn't contain JSON [it's not a string], it contains the result of *parsing* JSON.)

Comment: When i put it in my code, it does not work.

Comment: But i get what youre saying, and thank you very much.

Comment: Yeah, it may not be exactly correct, but the idea is to point you in the right direction. (I'm surprised though, I think this is a pretty accurate translation of what you had that you said worked...)