# Uncatchable exception in Promise.all

Tags: javascript, exception, async-await, try-catch

I tried this in a browser and node.js. I get an `Uncaught (in promise) Error: here` ... I have no idea why the try catch can't get it.

Anyone can solve this mystery ?

```
fct = async (msg) => {
    throw new Error(msg)
}

delayedValue = (value) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(value), 1000));

(async () => {
    try {
        console.log(await Promise.all([
            fct(await delayedValue('here')),
            fct(await delayedValue('it is')),
        ]));
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('catched', e);
    }
})();
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310521/node-js-best-practice-exception-handling/36703397#36703397) *might* help.

Comment: Why are you using `await` inside the `Promise.all` arguments?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen with node v18.15.0 i get this output :
```
> Uncaught Error: here
    at fct (REPL3:2:11)
> catched Error: here
    at fct (REPL3:2:11)
(node:70851) PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled asynchronously (rejection id: 1)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

Comment: @freedomn-m Actually no, it doesn't

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the feedback - I did a quick search on async exceptions and that was a detailed answer.

Comment: @Bergi it's because i didn't want to make intermediate variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the combination of `await`s and un-`await`ed async function calls. The code is executed as

```
const value1 = await delayedValue('here');
const promise1 = fct(value1);
const value2 = await delayedValue('it is');
const promise2 = fct(value2);
await Promise.all([promise1, promise2]);
```

which is a [well-known](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46889290/1048572) [antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45285129/1048572) that causes exactly the problem you are experiencing. `promise1` is a promise that is getting rejected before it gets a handler attached<sup>1</sup> via `Promise.all`. It's already being rejected while the `delayedValue('it is')` promise is `await`ed, and that's causing an unhandled rejection error.

It's not clear how exactly you wanted the code to run, you might be looking for any of

- ```js
  const value1 = await delayedValue('here');
  const value2 = await fct(value1);
  const value3 = await delayedValue('it is');
  const value4 = await fct(value3);
  console.log([value2, value4]);
  ```
- ```js
  const [value1, value2] = await Promise.all([
    delayedValue('here'),
    delayedValue('it is'),
  ]);
  console.log(await Promise.all([
    fct(value1),
    fct(value2),
  ]));
  ```
- ```js
  console.log(await Promise.all([
    delayedValue('here').then(fct),
    delayedValue('it is').then(fct),
  ]));
  ```
- ```js
  const value1 = await delayedValue('here');
  const [value2, value4] = await Promise.all([
    fct(value1),
    delayedValue('it is').then(fct)
  ]);
  console.log([value2, value4]);
  ```

All of these will fail fast and handle any error from any of the called functions immediately in a surrounding `try`/`catch` block.

<sub>1: More precisely, the handler must be attached "immediately", during the same microtask (loop?), possibly after the promise is rejected - it's fine when `fct()` returns an already-rejected promise. Either way, `await delayedValue()` is not acceptable before the rejection handler is attached.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your explication easy to understand, and references. I think i will still need to dive a bit more in it to perfectly understand what's happening here ^^

Answer (score 0):

In `fct(await delayedValue('here'))`, `await` makes the IIFE wait 1 second for `delayedValue('here')`, which then passes `'here'` to `fct()`, which in turn throws an error.

At this time of the event loop, `await delayedValue('it is')` has yet to return anything, which means the IIFE is still waiting for it and haven't execute `catch`.

That being said, `catch` eventually catches the error, but one second late.