# Is this the right use of Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

I have been exploring `Promises` for a while in **JavaScript** and thought of getting better at it.

I made a small blog app in **Node**. The scenario is whenever a user is deleted I want to delete all the blogs created by the user and also remove the user from the `likes` of the blog.

Below is the code for it.

```js
        const user = req.user;

        console.log(user);

        // Finding the blogs created by the user and creating an array of promises
        const createdBlogs = await Blog.find({creator: user._id});
        const createdBlogsPromises = createdBlogs.map(async blog => await Blog.findByIdAndDelete(blog._id));
        
        // Finding the blogs liked by the user and creating an array of promises
        // removeUser is an instance method in blogSchema
        const likedBlogs = await Blog.find({likes: {$in: user._id}});
        const likedBlogsPromises = likedBlogs.map(async blog => await blog.removeUser(user));

        // Using all method for parallel execution of promises
        const promiseResponse = await Promise.all([...createdBlogsPromises, ...likedBlogsPromises]);

        console.log(promiseResponse);
        
        await User.deleteOne({_id: user._id});

        res.status(204).json({message: 'Successfully deleted!!'});
```

I am using `Promise.all()` for this. Is this the right way to use `Promise.all()` or is there an alternative and easy way to perform this ?

Answer (score 2):

This is about right, but there are two problems:

- Instead of calling `Blog.findByIdAndDelete(blog._id)` and `blog.removeUser(user)` (which I supposed actually does remove the *likes*?) many times, the blog repository service should ideally have methods like `Blog.deleteAll(blogIds)` where you can pass an array of elements to operate on. This would be significantly faster if supported by the underlying storage layer (database?) as a single command.
- You are constructing the `createdBlogsPromises`, but then before waiting for them you first do another `await Blog.find(…)`. If there's an error in both of those, only the `await`ed promise rejection can be handled by the caller (e.g. with `try`/`catch`), but the other error will result in an unhandled promise rejection that crashes your server. See [Waiting for more than one concurrent await operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46889290/waiting-for-more-than-one-concurrent-await-operation) and [Any difference between await Promise.all() and multiple await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45285129/any-difference-between-await-promise-all-and-multiple-await) for details.
  Notice it's not the `Promsie.all` that "executes" the promises (as indicated in your comment), the asynchronous code starts running when you call it. Promises are just a mechanism to wait for the results.

  You can fix this by immediately `await`ing the array of promises:

  ```
  const createdBlogs = await Blog.find({creator: user._id});
  await Promise.all(createdBlogs.map(blog => Blog.findByIdAndDelete(blog._id)));

  const likedBlogs = await Blog.find({likes: {$in: user._id}});
  await Promise.all(likedBlogs.map(blog => blog.removeUser(user)));

  await User.deleteOne({_id: user._id});
  ```

  However, this means everything runs sequentially now, which you didn't intend. (Also, even in your original code `createdBlogs` and `likedBlogs` were found sequentially, which is not necessary). You can refactor this for full concurrency as

  ```
  async function deleteCreatedBlogs(user) {
    const createdBlogs = await Blog.find({creator: user._id});
    await Promise.all(createdBlogs.map(blog => Blog.findByIdAndDelete(blog._id)));
  }

  async function removeLikes(user) {
    const likedBlogs = await Blog.find({likes: {$in: user._id}});
    await Promise.all(likedBlogs.map(blog => blog.removeUser(user)));
  }

  async function deleteUser(user) {
    await User.deleteOne({_id: user._id});
  }
  ```

  then in your request handler do only

  ```
  await Promise.all([
    deleteCreatedBlogs(user),
    removeLikes(user),
    deleteUser(user),
  ]);
  ```

  or alternatively, using `.then()` instead of the helper functions,

  ```
  await Promise.all([
    Blog.find({creator: user._id}).then(createdBlogs => 
      Promise.all(createdBlogs.map(blog => Blog.findByIdAndDelete(blog._id)))
    ),
    Blog.find({likes: {$in: user._id}}).then(likedBlogs =>
      Promise.all(likedBlogs.map(blog => blog.removeUser(user)))
    ),
    User.deleteOne({_id: user._id}),
  ]);
  ```