# How to correctly implement and use chunking and batching a collection of promises/async functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, scheduling, promise.all

I am facing two scenarios when batch processing a large collection of async functions:

1. Collect all the async functions:

```
import { chunk } from "lodash";

const func = async () =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    const data = [...Array(500000).keys()];
    data.find((d) => d === Math.floor(Math.random() * 50000));
    resolve("resolved");
  });
const start = Date.now();
const promises = Array.from({ length: 100 }).map((_i) => func());

const chunkedPromises = chunk(promises, 25);
for (const batchedPromises of chunkedPromises) {
  await Promise.allSettled(batchedPromises);
}
console.log("Time taken: ", Date.now() - start);
```

(which start executing when pushed to a collection) and then send to a method that will chunk these into a batch of async functions and do `await Promise.allSettled(batchedPromises)` and collate the result per batch!

2. Collect a reference to all the async functions:

```
import { chunk } from "lodash";

const func = async () =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    const data = [...Array(500000).keys()];
    data.find((d) => d === Math.floor(Math.random() * 50000));
    resolve("resolved");
  });
const start = Date.now();
const asyncFuncs = Array.from({ length: 100 }).map((_i) => () => func());

const chunkedFuncs = chunk(asyncFuncs, 25);

for (const batchedFuncs of chunkedFuncs) {
  await Promise.allSettled(batchedFuncs.map((fn) => fn()));
}
console.log("Time taken: ", Date.now() - start);
```

and then send these to a method that will batch the references and do `await Promise.allSettled(batchedFuncs.map(fn => fn()))` and collate the result per batch!

**Note**: `func` is for demonstration purpose only. It could be any real world `asnyc` function.

How nodejs would execute both of above scenarios?

Would you ever use option 1? If yes, why?

When would you use option 2 and why?

Comment: Your question is very vague, please expand what you are trying to do, and/or provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @AndréLehto - Not entirely sure which part of the question is vague for you?

Comment: @the_conquest It's unclear whether you are talking about a collection of functions or a collection of promises. They are not the same. You seem to confuse the two terms multiple times in your question, leading to sentences that don't make sense and muddle the distinction between your two scenarios.. Please [edit] to clarify

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but you still have "*collect all the async functions (which start executing when pushed to a collection)*", "*batch process a collection of promises*", and "*batch a collection of promises*" (in the title).

Comment: It might help if you could show the implementation of the method that you intend to send these collections to.

Comment: Seems like you want something like this: https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-queue

Comment: By "batch", you mean creating multiple chunks from the collection, right?

Comment: If you use option1 then your queue will not impose any limit on how many async operations can Begin.  However it will still batch up responses as expected.

Comment: As of your last edit your option 2 will take x4 longer. There is no sensible reason to chunk things in option 1, js will execute them all upon main codeblock termination, you will just resolve them 25 at a time. Second option makes more sense in terms of chunking, could be useful for making requests in each promise to not max out allowed simultaneous server connections or to otherwise manage load. In js for example to avoid lag between js life cycles (frames).

Comment: @AssGoblin69 - Are you suggesting option 2 is better? What changed your perspective compared to your comment below "If there is no state involved then there truly is no difference. In your both..." Just wanted some clarification. Thanks.

Comment: my stance didn't change, your question changed. It was about batching, there is no difference between Promise.all([promise,proimse]) and Promise.all([() =>promise,()=>proimse].map(f=>f())) other then state and timing that i mentioned in comments. Now the question is about chunking, and in terms of chunking first option simply does not work

Comment: Just to clarify terminology (am not expert by any means) since that's where the confusion came from. Batching is putting things together into single thing. Chunking is dividing thing into multiple things. If we are talking about single batch, there is no difference, as for example for your edited final example there would be no difference if there would be only 25 promises, other then state and timing that i mentioned. If we are talking now about chunking, then there is huge difference, and launching all promises at once (option 1) kills the very purpose of chunking.

Answer (score 1):

> Which one of above, if at all, is the correct way to batch process a collection of async functions and why?

Definitely the second.

As you noted yourself, in the first approach all the functions already start executing when you push the promises in the collection (in particular, when you call `getAsyncFunction()` during the `map`). There is no actual batching of the execution going on. The only thing this achieves is to create a [hazard to crash your application when an error occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45285129/any-difference-between-await-promise-all-and-multiple-await) since you are creating promises (that might reject) without immediately attaching an error hander.

But even in your second code snippet, the terminology <s>is messed up</s> was messed up before the edit. `getAsyncFunction` gets you a promise when calling it not an async function, and `promises` is a array of async functions not an array of promises (as are `chunkedPromises` and `batchedPromises`). Yes, naming things is hard, but it's important to be precise, at least about the type of the value, to avoid confusing other programmers (and your future self) who may have to read the code.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

As of your last edit your option 2 will take x4 longer. There is no sensible reason to chunk things in option 1, js will execute them all upon main codeblock termination, you will just resolve them 25 at a time.

Second option makes more sense in terms of chunking (next 25 will not be started before first 25 finish), could be useful for making requests in each promise to not max out allowed simultaneous server connections or to otherwise manage load. In js for example to avoid lag between js life cycles (frames).

**OLD ANSWER:**

There is **no definite right or wrong** way of doing things in this case, it depends on the specific use-case and what makes more sense or is more readable.

In other languages with **multi-threading** support it could make huge difference. You would want to start each process as soon as possible, because by the time you will start the last one most of them could be already finished. In Javascript however there would be no measurable difference, since your Promises even tho async, will **not run parallel** to your main thread. Instead they will be executed after you main code-block termination (true for both Javascript and NodeJS).

Performance or function wise both your options are basically identical, it's up to preference and what makes most sense for your situation.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Well I think there is a clear difference of logic in the two options. 

```
const getAsyncFunction = async () =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        return resolve(RESOLVED_MESSAGE);
      }, 500);
    });

// First option:
batchProcess([...Array(100).map(_i => getAsyncFunction()]);

// Second option
batchProcess([...Array(100).map(_i => () => getAsyncFunction()]);
```

Comment: First option will kick off all the promises around the same time so will take few micro seconds + timeout. Whereas, the second option will take batchSize * timeout + few micro seconds

Comment: Not quite sure what you had in mind with that example. In your original question it's about putting promises directly into array vs putting callbacks into array and calling them by map when Promise.all is called. Since there was no additional info I assumed question is about best practices, to which answer is there is none and it depends. As to actual logical differences there is only order of execution. Promises will be created in different order, which could be important in state driven logic. Otherwise if you have differences it's because you are awaiting each callback separately in 2nd?

Comment: You understood the question correctly and would be immensely helpful if you can expand on "it depends". Assume its not state driven logic and the promises are independent of each other!

Comment: If there is no state involved then there truly is no difference. In your both examples thing that you pass to Promise.all is an array of promises. In first case they were created at different times perhaps throughout your code, In second they were created back to back right before passing them to Promise.all. Only other scenario where there could be difference that comes to mind is if your promises are highly time sensitive (have to start at same time), and you have some long taking code in between creation of promises.