[UnhandledPromiseRejection]: Why try...catch handle promise rejection if the last promise rejects, but throws an error for intermediate rejections?


async function all(...params) {
  let result = [];
  for (let promise of params) {
    try {
      let res = await promise;
      result.push(res);
    } catch (e) {
      result.push({
        error: e
      });
    }
  }
  return result;
}

const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(3);
  }, 3000);
});

const promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    reject(1);
  }, 1000);
});

const promise3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(2);
  }, 2000);
});

all(promise1, promise2, promise3).then(console.log);



I'm working with an async function in JavaScript that processes multiple promises using a try...catch block to handle any potential errors.
I have tried debugging and found that the try catch works for if the last promise rejects and throws error if any intermediate promise rejects.

Why does the try...catch seem to only work if the last promise rejects?
How can I modify my code to correctly handle rejections for all promises without triggering unhandled promise rejections?


I see the "uncaught (in promise)" error in the console, but it still has {"error": 1} in the result.

Thanks Barmar, yes, the result array has the error object pushed, but that can be accessed only by adding a unhandledRejection handler globally. But this error is not being thrown when I reject the promise with 3 seconds and resolve others, that is the last promise to settle.

When I run the code snippet, it logs the array with all the results. The error is only noticed if I have DevTools open.

When your not-the-last Promise instances are rejected before the point at which the Promise is awaited, the runtime has no idea that the Promise will be awaited at some point in the future. When it is rejected, therefore, all the runtime knows is that the rejection happened, the Promise is not in an await expression and there is no .catch() handler, so that's an unhandled exception.

It looks like you are trying to reinvent Promise.all or Promise.allSettled.

Yes, Bergi, I was trying to build a polyfill for allSettled, but encountered this error.

"found that the try catch […] throws error" - nope. It's the reject(1); that is causing the error. The rejected promise is not being awaited (or has any other .then() handlers attached to it) at the time it gets rejected, so it gets reported as an unhandled promise rejection. The try doesn't even see that rejection, which is the whole problem.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46889290/waiting-for-more-than-one-concurrent-await-operation and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45285129/any-difference-between-await-promise-all-and-multiple-await

Hi Bergi, I went through the mentioned questions, so is it, that the line reject(1) inside setTimeout (line 24), where the error is thrown from and not from try block ?

Yes, exactly. If it was thrown from the try block, a all(promise1, promise2, promise3).catch(console.log) would've caught it

@JaromandaX The arguments to this function are promises, not functions. I don't see why it matters whether they're in an array or separate arguments, the ...params syntax converts one to the other.

@Barmar - oops, sorry, misread :p as for "why it matters" ... OP suggests they are creating a polyfill for allSettled - but allSettled has a defined syntax :p

The uncaught rejections
The issue is that the posted code waits consecutively for each promise in the argument list to settle before adding a catch handler to promises passed later in the argument list.
Using the posted code as an example,

await effectively adds a pair of onfulfilled and onrejected handlers to a promise operand so that when it becomes settled, await can return the fulfilled value or throw the rejection reason. So the awaited promise won't generate an "uncaught promise rejection" error because it has a rejection handler.

the first promise awaited in the synchronous for..of loop is promise1 which takes 3 seconds to fulfill.

During those 3 seconds the await operator returns control to the event loop, the timers for promise2 and promise3 expire and reject their promises - which without a catch handler are treated as uncaught rejections.


Solution
The solution is to add handlers to all of the promises before waiting for any of them, or alternatively don't use await and add handlers that effectively implement the Promise static method that is being polyfilled.
Real Example
<disclaimer> this is code for a Promise.all polyfill written in ES3 as part of promise experimentation. Provided FYI, usual conditions of "provided as is", "don't sue me", etc apply.</disclaimer>
  function assertPromiseClass( oThis, method) {
    if( oThis === Promise || oThis  instanceof PromiseClass) {
      return oThis;
    }
    if( (!oThis && bNode)|| (bNode && oThis === Global) ) { // Promise/A+ testing?
      return Promise;
    }
    if( isFunction( oThis) && isFunction( oThis.resolve)
     && isObject( oThis.prototype)  && isFunction( oThis.prototype.then) ) {
      return oThis;
    }
    var msg = "Assert Promise."+method+" called on a Promise-like constructor failed.";
    console.trace();
    console.error( "this value: ", oThis);
    throw new Error( msg);
  }

  Promise.all = function( arg) {        // Promise.all
    var array;
    var C = assertPromiseClass( this, "all");
    return new C( function(resolve, reject) {
      if( !(array = from(arg))) {
        reject( new TypeError("Promise.all unable to iterate over " + arg));
        return;
      }
      var   todo = array.length;
      var   done = false;
      var results = [];
      function slowResolve(i, data) {
        if(!done) {
          results[i] = data;
          if( --todo == 0) {
            done = true;
            resolve( results);
            results = null;
          }
        }
      }
      function fastFail( err) {
        if( !done) {
          done = true;
          reject(err);
          results = null;
        }
      }
      if( array.length) {
        each( array, function( promise, i) {
          promise = C.resolve( promise);
          bChain = false;
          promise.then( function( data) { slowResolve(i, data)}, fastFail);
          bChain = true;
        });
      }
      else {
        resolve( results);
      }
    });
  };

The above functions are in an IIFE - Promise is an argument, an bChain is an optimization to prevent the polyfilled then method from returning a promise.
