Elegant way to use a big Promise.all?
I am working on a game and I have a spot in the code where I load all the resources in parallel. Currently it looks something like this:
let [
    grassTexture,
    stoneTexture,
    waterTexture,
    birdSound,
    bellSound,
    choochooSound
] = await Promise.all([
    loadGrassTexture(),
    loadStoneTexture(),
    loadWaterTexture(),
    loadBirdSound(),
    loadBellSound(),
    loadChoochooSound()
])

but that doesn't strike me as particularly well-designed since it's easy to mess up the order (the association between loadee and loader) and it would be better if the result was on the same line with the respective function call. Another option I see is this:
let grassTexturePromise = loadGrassTexture()
let stoneTexturePromise = loadStoneTexture()
let waterTexturePromise = loadWaterTexture()
let birdSoundPromise = loadBirdSound()
let bellSoundPromise = loadBellSound()
let choochooSoundPromise = loadChoochooSound()

let grassTexture = await grassTexturePromise
let stoneTexture = await stoneTexturePromise
let waterTexture = await waterTexturePromise
let birdSound = await birdSoundPromise
let bellSound = await bellSoundPromise
let choochooSound = await choochooSoundPromise

but that's not much better. Is there some idiomatic way to do this?
EDIT:
I apologize that this is such a moving target, I simplified too much for this post. In my code I am using typescript and the resources have different types. I also corrected the second listing according to the comments.

Why not put the function references in an array also?

@Pointy what do you mean? They are in an array, no?

"Another option I see is this:" yeah, don't do it that way. 1. it doesn't really do what you want (the *Texture variables will still remain promises) 2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54291660

You can use Promise.allSettled, output is a bit more complicated that the one from Promise.all but you received information which ones were rejected and which were fulfilled (order is also preserved)

The two code blocks are not equivalent. In the first you're setting the variables to the async function results. In the second you're setting them to the promises, not the results.

@Yogi I think he just means that it's easy to get the variables in the destructuring pattern in the wrong order compared to the functions, so the variables get the wrong values.

You should not have X load????Texture functions. Instead think of one function that takes an argument to determine which texture to load.

Instead of using separate variables for each resource, put them in an object keyed by the resource names.
Then you can use Promise.all() followed by a loop to fill in the values.
const textures = {
    grass: loadGrassTexture(),
    stone: loadStoneTexture(),
    // ...
};

const results = await Promise.all(Object.values(textures));
Object.keys(textures).forEach((key, i) => textures[key] = results[i]);


Thanks! This looks the most elegant to me. However, I think this is not going to work with TypeScript. I am sorry I forgot to mention that I am using TypeScript...

I don't use TypeScript, but with what little I know about it I don't see why it wouldn't work.

You could refactor this to a parametrized function:

//if you can refactor you code to a parameterized load texture function 

async function loadTexture(textureName) {
  //your new code here
}

const textureNames = ['grass', 'stone', 'water', 'sky', 'sand', 'wood', 'carpet', 'paper', 'steel'];

const texturePromises = textureNames.map(async (name) => [name, await loadTexture(name)]);
const textureEntries = await Promise.all(texturePromises);
//now we have a mapping of texture type -> texture
const textureObject = Object.fromEntries(textureEntries);


I recommend to make a separate namespace file.
For example:
loaders.mjs
// PLACE NECESSARY IMPORTS HERE

// The functions below should return Promises.

export const grassTexture  = loadGrassTexture();
export const stoneTexture  = loadStoneTexture();
export const waterTexture  = loadWaterTexture();
export const skyTexture    = loadSkyTexture();
export const sandTexture   = loadSandTexture();
export const woodTexture   = loadWoodTexture();
export const carpetTexture = loadCarpetTexture();
export const paperTexture  = loadPaperTexture();
export const steelTexture  = loadSteelTexture();

// The order below doesn't matter...
export default Promise.all
([
   grassTexture, stoneTexture, waterTexture,
   skyTexture, sandTexture, woodTexture,
   carpetTexture, paperTexture, steelTesture,
]);

Then in any other file you can load them like this:
// Import the loaders at the script root.
import texturePromises, * as loaders from './loaders.mjs';

// Then use at an asynchronous thread...
async function installTextures ()
{
   // Stops the thread until all Promises are fulfilled.
   await texturePromises;
   
   // From here on everything is loaded...
   
   // Note that the order doesn't matter.
   const { paperTexture, skyTexture } = loaders;
   
   // Use as needed.
}

// Or import just the needed part for a specific component directly...
import { stoneTexture, grassTexture, waterTexture } from './loaders.mjs';

Note that the await keyword will stop a thread until the respective Promise is fulfilled. Make sure to use only when really needed. In most cases is better to rely on the .then() method.

If you're not dead set on vanilla javascript, you could consider Bluebird.props:
let {
    grassTexture,
    stoneTexture,
    ...
} = await Bluebird.props({
    grassTexture: loadGrassTexture(),
    stoneTexture: loadStoneTexture(),
    ...
})

