# Call async/await functions in parallel not working on React's componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I'm trying to call the same this.func twice asynchronously, this.func makes a http request but I can see through the network tab that these two functions are not running in parallel. I've already read these answers: [answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612428/call-async-await-functions-in-parallel), [answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42158853/how-run-async-await-in-parallel-in-javascript)

```
    async componentDidMount() {     
   //...
    var applicationVersion2 = await Promise.all([this.func(this.state.applicationUrl), this.func(this.state.applicationUrl2)]); 
   //...
    }
```

how it is now:

[image]

how it should be:

[image]

Comment: There is only a limited number of workers, that might explain why not all 14 calls run in parallel.

Comment: Not to state the obvious here but are you sure that `this.func` is async and/or returns a promise?  The top graph is exactly what I would expect from two non-async functions run in series.

Comment: It will probably help if you show what this. func does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments above, I suspect that `this.func` isn't asynchronous code and/or returning a promise although without seeing it, it's hard to say for sure.  Try this:

```
async componentDidMount() {     
  //...
  const first = this.func(this.state.applicationUrl)
  console.log(`First: ${first}`)   
  const second = this.func(this.state.applicationUrl2)
  console.log(`Second: ${second}`) 
  const applicationVersion2 = [await first, await second]
  //...
}
```

In your console.log, you *should* see:

```
First: Promise {<pending>}
Second: Promise {<pending>}
```

But I'm guessing you'll see a non-promise value from both.  If that's the case, make `this.func` an `async function` or return a `Promise` from it.

Comment: I tried and it saw `First: [object Promise]` on console but on the network tab it looks the same of my first print. Here is a [print](https://imgur.com/V8E3MFc) of the code (some funcs and vars are wirh different names). If you can't reproduce my problem, let me know I will share the full code of the project

Comment: @Eduardo Actually, it would be helpful if you could add the code (copy and paste) of those two functions to your original post.

Comment: Nevermind.  See here: https://gist.github.com/jayallen/746f122d70301502dcd0ad5bb46015cc  That code definitely loads the resources concurrently.  I'm not sure what the issue if with your code. :-/

Comment: I tried your code on new project it worked, I will search on my code what's wrong and when I find I'll post here, thank you for your help

Comment: @Eduardo I’m glad to hear it and hope that it helps!