# Wait function not happening in parallel

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have some piece of asynchronous code which is currently being executed one by one. I understand there is a way to execute this in parallel but couldn't find out the syntax to do. this is how it looks at the moment

```
async function someAsyncFunc(i) {
   await wait(i);
   return i;
}

async function wait(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}

function doSomething() {
  const arr = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000];

  arr.forEach(item => {
    someAsyncFunc(item)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
      })
  });
  console.log("finished");
}

doSomething();
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How run async / await in parallel in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42158853/how-run-async-await-in-parallel-in-javascript)

Comment: "*which is currently being executed one by one.*" - no, it's not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close to what you are looking for. You need to use `Promise.all` and use map inside it.

By the way the current version using `forEach` is not correct as promise doesn't value `forEach`. You should use `for...of`

```
async function someAsyncFunc(i) {
  await wait(i);
  return i;
}

async function wait(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}

function doSomething() {
  const arr = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000];

  Promise.all(arr.map(item => {
    return someAsyncFunc(item);
  }))
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  });
}

doSomething();
```

Comment: perfect. this is what I was looking for.

Comment: promise doesn't value `forEach`? why so Promise got ego problem? :P

Comment: @AZ_ you can check on this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach - this will tell you about ego problem or not. see section - Note on using Promises or async functions

Comment: https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404 , https://www.coreycleary.me/why-does-async-await-in-a-foreach-not-actually-await/ ... rest I am sure you could google and find out links.. hope this clears your doubt.