# (node.js version 7 or above, not C#) multiple await call with node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, generator

i used to use the generator function, and it is really easy to use.
when i want to do multiple asynchronous calls, i just simple use code like this

```
// all calls will be execute in the same time (no wait)
const resultA = yield callServiceA()
const resultB = yield callServiceB()
const resultC = yield callServiceC()

if (resultA && resultB && resultC) {
  // we got results from all services now, 
}
```

how to migrate the code above to use `async` and `await` keyword on node.js version 7 or above

Comment: @josh3736, please answer my question

Comment: Oops, wrong link.  Actually answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612428/call-async-await-functions-in-parallel