# How to combine responses to an array using spread?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have responses from both promises but when i `combineResponse` it only resolve one response from `ptmResponse` promise , What is implemented wrong in below code using spread ? response is coming as object that i want to push it to array.

> main.ts

```
try {
  const __data: IResponse = await makeRequest(this._request);
  const specResponse = await this.specResponse(__data.Details[0]);
  const ptmResponse = await this.ptmAccountBalanceResponse(__data.Details[1]);
  const combineResponse = {
    ...specResponse,
    ...ptmResponse
  };
  return Promise.resolve(combineResponse);
} catch (err) {
  return Promise.reject(err);
}
```

Comment: What are `specResponse` and `specResponse`? Objects? Arrays?

Comment: if specResponse is an empty object, for example, then it won't spread anything into combineResponse

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612428/call-async-await-functions-in-parallel), no?

Comment: response is an object

Comment: @aaron i see response from both but when i combined it only resolve to one

Comment: What are those objects' properties? If both have the same keys, `ptmResponse` will overwrite what's in `specResponse`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be overthinking this one. I'm assuming you want an array containing both objects. If so, then it's just:

```
const combineResponse = [ specResponse, ptmResponse ]
```

No spread needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would also fire those promises in parallel with [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and store both responses in `combineResponse` as an array:

```
const combineResponse = await Promise.all([this.specResponse(__data.Details[0]), this.ptmAccountBalanceResponse(__data.Details[1])]);
```