# Javascript - Call two async functions parallel and pass both results to a third one

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mongoose, es6-promise

I want to call two mongoose queries "**Parallel**" and pass the returned data of both the queries to client side.

```
//both queries should be called parallel, not one after another

//query 1
PaperModel.find().then((papers) => {
});

//query 2
ConferenceModel.find().then((conferences) => {
});

//this function should only be called when both the
//queries have returned the data
res.render('Home', {
    Papers: papers
    Conferences: conferences
});
```

I tried to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612428/call-async-await-functions-in-parallel) but didn't get it well. Thanks

Comment: It is as simple as `await Promise.all([someCall(), anotherCall()]);` what did you not get? What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If PaperModel.find() and ConferenceModel.find() returning promises you can use something like in code below:

```
//query 1
const papers = PaperModel.find();

//query 2
const conferences = ConferenceModel.find();

Promise.all([papers, conferences]).then((values) => {
    res.render('Home', {
        Papers: values[0]
        Conferences: values[1]
    });
})
```

and another option with wrapping function with async await syntax

```
const getData = async () => {
  const papers = PaperModel.find();
  const conferences = ConferenceModel.find();

  const values = await Promise.all([papers, conferences]);

  res.render('Home', {
    Papers: values[0]
    Conferences: values[1]
  });
}
```