# Javascript/Typescript How to run async functions in parallel?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, async-await

I have a piece of code which runs 4 `async` functions:

```
this.groupsLevels = await this.groupsLevelsService.getData();
this.indicators = await this.configurationService.getIndicators();
this.sources = await this.configurationService.getSources();
this.storeGroups = await this.storeGroupsService.getStoreGroups();

console.log(this.groupsLevels) // All of them is populated
console.log(this.indicators)   // All of them is populated
console.log(this.sources)      // All of them is populated
console.log(this.storeGroups)  // All of them is populated
```

How Can I run all of 4 in parallel ? and get the final result when all of them is done.?

I tried

```
Promise.all([
  async () => {this.groupsLevels = await this.groupsLevelsService.getData(); },
  async () => {this.indicators = await this.configurationService.getIndicators(); },
  async () => {this.sources = await this.configurationService.getSources(); },
  async () => {this.storeGroups = await this.storeGroupsService.getStoreGroups(); },
]);

console.log(this.groupsLevels) 
console.log(this.indicators)   
console.log(this.sources)      
console.log(this.storeGroups)
```

But no one was loaded successfully.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612428/call-async-await-functions-in-parallel). :)

Comment: the answer that you quote does not returns a value.

Comment: Take as a side note that JS is single threaded and _async_ does not mean _in parallel_

Comment: [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) returns a promise. So you can use ```.then(() => { })```. You can pass your data to variables and after your then you can access those variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for

```
[this.groupsLevels, this.indicators, this.sources, this.storeGroups] = await Promise.all([
  this.groupsLevelsService.getData(),
  this.configurationService.getIndicators(),
  this.configurationService.getSources(),
  this.storeGroupsService.getStoreGroups(),
]);

console.log(this.groupsLevels);
console.log(this.indicators);
console.log(this.sources); 
console.log(this.storeGroups);
```

Comment: Great.  I never seen this notation `[x,y,z] = ...` What does it means? It is part of which ES ?

Comment: @DanielSantos It's array destructuring, available since ES6. More commonly used with variable declarations, but you can use any target expression in the elements :-)