# fetch data from multiple apis with async await

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

Async/await has come in handy when fetching data asynchronously, especially in the

```
async componentDidMount() {
    try {
       const response = await axios.get(endpoints.one)
       const data = await response
       this.setState({ data, isLoading: false })
    } catch (e) {
       this.setState({ errors: e.response })
    }

}
```

Moreover, when fetching from multiple endpoints, one can easily use

```
Promise.all([
  fetch(endpoints.one),
  fetch(endpoints.two),
]).then(([data1, data2]) => {
  console.log(data1, data2)
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

However, how can one use **aync/await** to fetch data from multiples sources instead of **Promise.all**?

Comment: You can await ```Promise.all()```.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612428/call-async-await-functions-in-parallel)

Comment: some answers from here provide solutions without `Promise.all`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612428/call-async-await-functions-in-parallel

Comment: you can simply await Promise.all()

Answer (score 12):

If you want to do them in parallel, then you'll still Promise.all. Just you'll `await` the result rather than calling `.then`

```
async someFunction() {
  try {
    const [data1, data2] = await Promise.all([
      fetch(endpoints.one),
      fetch(endpoints.two),
    ]);
    console.log(data1, data2);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: A good idea, however when you are doing it the componentDidMount....  `async componentDidMount() { someFunction() }`  you do not get data in the response

Comment: Are you referring to the fact that i didn't have a return statement in my example?

Comment: @ErickMwazonga what do you mean by "you do not get data in the response"? are you just referring to the missing `this.setState` in his answer? or something else?