# How to execute two async functions in parallell and then wait for them to complete?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to fetch data from two different APIs and want this to happen in parallell but then I want to wait for them to execute and then continue with the next line of code.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
    this.fetch1() // <-- Async method
    this.fetch2() // <-- Async method
    this.func(); // The above two lines of code needs to be done to execute this line

  }

  async fetch1() {
    fetch("/api/abc123")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
          this.setState({ foo: res });
      });
  }

  async fetch2() {
    fetch("/api/def456")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
          this.setState({ bar: res });
      });
  }

func() {
    // Do something with the data from the APIs
  }
```

Comment: Also possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/31424561/1260204

Comment: Maybe use async on componentDidMount and then use await on your fetches. const fetchOne = await fetch1();

Comment: Also a possibility [Call async/await functions in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612428/call-async-await-functions-in-parallel/35612484)

Answer (score 2):

```
const promises = []
for(let request of requests){ promises.push(request) }

Promise.all(promises).then(res => /*res[0], res[1]*/)
```

[`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) will only resolve when all requests are done, and deliver then in an `response` array in the order passed.

Answer (score 1):

I use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios), it has `axios.all()` for multiple requess, have a look at these [examples](https://github.com/axios/axios#example)

> Performing multiple concurrent requests
>   (code from the link)

```
function getUserAccount() {   
     return axios.get('/user/12345'); 
}

function getUserPermissions() {   
    return axios.get('/user/12345/permissions'); 
}

axios.all([getUserAccount(), getUserPermissions()])  
.then(axios.spread(function (acct, perms) {
    // Both requests are now complete   
}));
```