# send a function as param to alert handler

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

i have this alertCtrl and i want to use it as a service, my idea is send 3 params to this alert, header, text and a function, this function will be fired when the user press the Ok button, i tryid to send params like this but this doesnt work.

this is my code:

```html
 async showMessage(header,message, function){
  let alert = await this.alertCtrl.create(
  {
    header: header,
    message: message,
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'Cancel'
      },
      {
        text: 'Ok',
        handler: () => {
          function // i  want to fire a function here
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  await alert.present();
  }
```

thanks in advance.

greetings

Answer (score 0):

You are not executing the function inside the handler try adding () like

```
function();
```

Comment: `function` is a keyword, so you cannot be using that unless to declare a function.

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**, the word `function` is a keyword, and should not be used unless you are declaring a function. In the modified code below, I have used `onOkClick` as the call back function, which you need to attach to the handler.

**Secondly**, you need not necessarily have 2 awaits unless you have 2 separate parallel events happening which needed to be combined. Even in that case, you will need something like `Promise.all` where you wait for the 2 async events to complete and then resolve them as one single entity. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612428/call-async-await-functions-in-parallel)

Try the below code and it should work.

```
async showMessage(header, message, onOkClick) {

  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      header: header,
      message: message,
      buttons: [{
          text: 'Cancel'
        }, {
          text: 'Ok',
          handler: onOkClick // attach callback
        ];
      });
  }

  await alert.present();

}
```