# Synchronous callback with different timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, settimeout

I am trying to console using a callback function, which itself is a callback function inside a setTimeout function. How can I get an orderly result?

I wish to have callback for f1 called, followed by f2 and finally f3, irrespective of their timer.

```
let f1 = (cb) => { 
    setTimeout(() => {
        cb(null, {a: 1})
    },100)
}

let f2 = (cb) => { 
    setTimeout(() => {
        cb(null, {a: 2})
    },50)
}

let f3 = (cb) => { 
    setTimeout(() => {
        cb(null, {a: 3})
    },10)
}

function parallelConsole(arr, cb) {
    let result = [];
    arr.forEach(func => {
        func((temp, val) => {
            console.log(val)
            result.push(val)
            if(arr.length === result.length) {
                cb(result)
            }      
        })
    })
}

parallelConsole([f1, f2, f3], (res) => {
    console.log(res) //[{a: 3}, {a: 2}, {a: 1}]
})
```

Expected Result: [{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a: 3}]

Actual Result: [{a: 3}, {a: 2}, {a: 1}]

Comment: Would you parellelize the executions or would you execute them sequentially? f3's timeout is shorter than f2's one that's shorter than the f'3 timeout. The result is obvious f3,f2,f1.

Comment: @Alessandro Yeah, I want the result to be f1,f2,f3. That's why I am here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call async/await functions in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612428/call-async-await-functions-in-parallel)

Comment: @Alessandro Irrespective of timer, I want to have f1 at result[0].

Comment: @StefanN Here, I did as mentioned in the link you shared. I'm still not getting the expected result.

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/0v923pLq/1/

Answer (score 1):

If you really have to work with callbacks and if this is for a production-related project, is using [async.js](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/) an option? It provides some really useful functions (and `.each` might be what you are looking for).

> I wish to have callback for f1 called, followed by f2 and finally f3, irrespective of their timer.

I'm a bit confused by this. If there's a timeout, then the callback will be called after the specified time has passed. Or do you want to `console.log` the result in an ordered manner (1, 2, 3) irrespective of when the callback has been called?

Edit: I've fixed a bit your code, so I think it does what you want. The `promise` from `f1, f2, f3` wasn't returned. Also, as pointed in the comments, using `Promise.all` can ensure that the final callback is called after all promises have been fulfilled.

```
const f1 = (cb) => {
  return new Promise ((resolve) => setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(cb(null, { a: 1 }))
  }, 100))
};

const f2 = (cb) => {
  return new Promise ((resolve) => setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(cb(null, { a: 2 }))
  }, 50))
};

const f3 = (cb) => {
  return new Promise ((resolve) => setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(cb(null, { a: 3 }))
  }, 10))
};

function parallelConsole(arr, cb) {
  return Promise.all(arr)
    .then((values) => {
      cb(null, values);
    });
}

const log = (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    // TODO: handle properly
    return console.log(err);
  }

  return data;
};

parallelConsole([f1(log), f2(log), f3(log)], (err, res) => {
  console.log(res)
});
```

Comment: Hi Denny, welcome to SO! I understand that you do not have enough points for a comment, but is indeed not an answer.

Comment: It'd be even better to just go all out on Promises and ditch the `cb` here :)

Answer (score 1):

```
let f1 = (cb) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    cb(null, { a: 1 });
  }, 100);
};

let f2 = (cb) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    cb(null, { a: 2 });
  }, 50);
};

let f3 = (cb) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    cb(null, { a: 3 });
  }, 10);
};

function parallelConsole(arr, cb) {
  let result = [];
  let offset = 0;

  const next = () => {
    if (arr.length === result.length) {
      return cb(result);
    }
    arr[offset]((temp, val) => {
      console.log(val);
      result.push(val);
      offset += 1;
      next();
    });
  };
  next();
}

parallelConsole([f1, f2, f3], (res) => {
  console.log(res); //[{a: 3}, {a: 2}, {a: 1}]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to go all out on [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) instead of callbacks, the code becomes somewhat more elegant:

```
// Promisified delay. Resolves with the given optional value after msec.
const delay = (msec, value) =>
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(value), msec));

// Call `cb` on the resolved value of `p`; resolve with the same value.
const tapPromise = (p, cb) =>
  p.then(v => {
    cb(v);
    return v;
  });

// Factories for the slow promises
const f1 = () => delay(100, { a: 1 });
const f2 = () => delay(50, { a: 2 });
const f3 = () => delay(10, { a: 3 });

// Create three promises and tap them with console.log.
// (They start executing right away, not when they're waited on.)
const promises = [f1(), f2(), f3()].map(p => tapPromise(p, console.log));

// Wait for all three promises to resolve, then log the results.
// Promise.all guarantees the order is the same as with the original promises.
Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
  console.log(results);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did a little refactoring on your solution. Do not use the array push method as you need to maintain the order of output. Use array index to store the result like: **result[index] = val; inside forEach**.

```js
let f1 = (cb) => { 
    setTimeout(() => {
        cb(null, {a: 1})
    },100)
}

let f2 = (cb) => { 
    setTimeout(() => {
        cb(null, {a: 2})
    },50)
}

let f3 = (cb) => { 
    setTimeout(() => {
        cb(null, {a: 3})
    },10)
}

function parallelConsole(arr, cb) {
    let result = [];
    arr.forEach((func, index) => {
        func((temp, val) => {
            result[index] = val;
            if(arr.length === result.length) {
                cb(result)
            }      
        })
    })
}

parallelConsole([f1, f2, f3], (res) => {
    console.log(res) //[{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a: 3}]
})
```