# How to render a page in same time execute a function call

Tags: node.js, typescript, handlebars.js, nestjs

Using NestJs with handlebars, I have the code below

```
@Post('/foo')
@Render('foo')
async foobar(){
    exemple();
    return {x: x, y: y};
}
```

My problem is: I need to call `exemaple ()` and not wait for it, proceed to`return`

I tried to [Call async/await functions in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612428/call-async-await-functions-in-parallel) but the `await Promise.all([...])` works only functions calls, i need to call `exemple` and render the page (in return)

EDIT--
The `exemple()` function is an shell command

```
var shell = require('shelljs')    
shell.exec('some command here')
```

Comment: So the return value of `example()` is not needed for the page rendering? It should just call the function an not care about its execution at all? Because if `example()` is asynchronous, that's exactly what your code is doing.

Comment: I also thought it would have exactly this behavior, but the page only renders when the `exemple()` finishes executing .. which to me does not make much sense.

Comment: What are you doing in `example()`? Is it really not a synchronous execution?

Comment: Its an shell commando call, i added in EDIT

Comment: Still having problems? :)

Comment: I did not forget to test your solution, but I have not had time to test, because I needed to change OS and I am having problems with this change. But I looked at the link you left and it looks pretty promising

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation of `exec()`](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs#execcommand--options--callback) it is not executed asynchronously unless a callback is provided or the `async` option is set to `true`.

So to solve your problem set it to async:

```
shell.exec('some command here', {async: true})
```