# Use async / await in parallel, and get results as they arrive?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I need to do multiple ajax fetches to populate a web page, and would like to render the different parts of the page as the results arrive. Is it possible to do this using async / await syntax, or do I have to do the older-style callbacks with promises?

This question is similar, but does not have the answer: [Call async/await functions in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612428/call-async-await-functions-in-parallel) The accepted answer in this question is to use Promise.all(...), which doesn't return *any* results until *all* of the results resolve.

I know I can do this with:

```
myPromise.then(function(value) {
  // populate part of page here
});

myOtherPromise.then(function(value) {
  // populate other part of page here
});
```

but I'm trying to use the newer await syntax.

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like:

```js
(async () => {
    const value = await myPromise;
    // then do your stuff with value
})();

(async () => {
    const value = await myOtherPromise;
    // then do your stuff with value
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

To my knowledge, it's not possible to do this because async/await is used to add synchronous patterns to asynchronous code. However, there are some other ways around this, one example being:

```
(async () => {
  const res = await fetch("https://example.com");
  document.querySelector("#example").innerHTML = await res.text();
})();

(async () => {
  alert("Is the internet on? " + ( await fetch("http://example.com/")).ok )
})();
```