# Resolving multiple fetch request in parallel

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to do a multiple parallel fetch requests in `react-native`. But i don't get the response data as expected. What am i integrating it wrongly?

```
async componentDidMount() {
    try {
        let [res1, res2] = await Promise.all([
            fetch(apiUrl1),
            fetch(apiUrl2),
        ]);

        console.warn(res1);
        console.warn(res2);
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.warn(err);
    };
}
```

THis is the weird response i got.

```
{"_bodyBlob": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "4", "offset": 0, "size": 661}}, "_bodyInit": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "", "offset": 0, "size": 661}}, "headers": {"map": {"cache-control": "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate", "cf-cache-status": "DYNAMIC", "cf-ray": "5", "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8", "date": "Thu, 09 Jan 2020 12:15:40 GMT", "expect-ct": "max-age=604800, report-uri=\"https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct\"", "expires": "", "pragma": "no-cache", "server": "cloudflare", "set-cookie": "ci_session=; expires=; Max-Age=7200; path=/; HttpOnly"}}, "ok": true, "status": 200, "statusText": undefined, "type": "default", "url": "apiurl"}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call async/await functions in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612428/call-async-await-functions-in-parallel)

Comment: @IsmaelPadilla unfortunately not. That is the exact same code i implemented as u have seen but it does not work for request using `fetch API`. It should have been the right way of using `Promise.All` for parallel request but the problem is how to make it work with `fetch API`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the below code if your response is coming in json

```
 let [res1, res2] = await Promise.all([
            fetch(apiUrl1).then(response => response.json()),
            fetch(apiUrl2).then(response => response.json()),
        ]);
```

Answer (score 23):

I'm a bit late, but it seemed like a good idea to show you how to perform multiple requests and wait for their resolution using only `Promise.all` and `async`/`await`.

The code below also shows how to handle errors correctly for multiple HTTP requests. I mention this because due to the way `fetch()` works, the `catch` block of your code will not be executed when HTTP errors occur:

> A `fetch()` promise only rejects when a network error is encountered
> (which is usually when there’s a permissions issue or similar). A
> `fetch()` promise does not reject on HTTP errors (404, etc.). Instead, a
> `then()` handler must check the `Response.ok` and/or `Response.status`
> properties. – Taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch)

```js
(async () => {
  try {
    const urls = [
      "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random",
      "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random",
      "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random",
      "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random",
    ];

    const requests = urls.map((url) => fetch(url));
    const responses = await Promise.all(requests);
    const errors = responses.filter((response) => !response.ok);

    if (errors.length > 0) {
      throw errors.map((response) => Error(response.statusText));
    }

    const json = responses.map((response) => response.json());
    const data = await Promise.all(json);

    data.forEach((datum) => console.log(datum));
  }
  catch (errors) {
    errors.forEach((error) => console.error(error));
  }
})();
```

For clarity, I also leave you an equivalent method using `then()`:

```js
(() => {
  const urls = [
    "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random",
    "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random",
    "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random",
    "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random",
  ];
  const requests = urls.map((url) => fetch(url));

  Promise.all(requests)
    .then((responses) => {
      const errors = responses.filter((response) => !response.ok);

      if (errors.length > 0) {
        throw errors.map((response) => Error(response.statusText));
      }

      const json = responses.map((response) => response.json());
      return Promise.all(json);
    })
    .then((data) => {
      data.forEach((datum) => console.log(datum));
    })
    .catch((errors) => {
      errors.forEach((error) => console.error(error));
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 5):

> The Promise.all() method returns a single Promise that fulfills when
>   all of the promises passed as an iterable have been fulfilled or when
>   the iterable contains no promises. It rejects with the reason of the
>   first promise that rejects. - From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

What you just did there is assign a Promise resolve to a variable and then console.log it. Which is not what you want. Something like this should give the results you want?

```
async componentDidMount() {
    try {
        await Promise.all([
            fetch(apiUrl1),
            fetch(apiUrl2),
        ]).then([res1, res2] => {    
            console.warn(res1);
            console.warn(res2); 
        });
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.warn(err);
    };
}
```