# Could someone please explain me the following with async/await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

could someone please explain this code in depth?

```
const promiseFactory = () =>
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(1), 5000));
```

If I call this with the following:

```
const consumer = async() => {
  promiseFactory().then(s => console.log(s));
  console.log("next step");
}
```

will output "next step" and after 5seconds
but if I call it with the following,

```
const consumer = async() => {
  const val = await promiseFactory();
  console.log(val);
  console.log("next step");
}
```

will output 1 and then "next step"
So in the end promises and async/await are not just a syntax difference?

Comment: There is a good discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612428/call-async-await-functions-in-parallel?rq=1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607692/understanding-the-event-loop

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> const consumer = async() => {
> promiseFactory().then(s => console.log(s));
>   console.log("next step");
> }
> ```

1. You call `promiseFactory`
2. You call `console.log("next step");
3. At some point in the future the promise resolves and you call `console.log(s)`

> ```
> const consumer = async() => {
>   const val = await promiseFactory();
>   console.log(val);
>   console.log("next step");
> }
> ```

1. You can `promiseFactory`
2. At some point in the future the promise resolves and you call `console.log(val)` and then `console.log("next step")`

---

> So in the end promises and async/await are not just a syntax difference?

They, essentially are, you are just not writing equivalent code.

Your use of `async` and `await` is equivalent to:

```
const consumer = async () => {
    promiseFactory().then(s => {
        console.log(s);
        console.log("next step");
    );
};
```

with *all* the code after the `await` in the callback to `then`, not just the next line.

And your use of `then` would be equivalent to:

```
const consumer = async() => {
  doAsyncStuff();
  console.log("next step");
}

const doAsyncStuff = async () {
    const s = await promiseFactory();
    console.log(s)
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'm aware of this, my question would be, how can the equivalent code be written to your code block above with async/await?

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to put the `console.log("next step");` into the `then` of the promise. Javascript doesn't stop execution. With await, you're waiting first, then continuing execution.

```
const consumer = /* you don't need the async here */ () => {
  promiseFactory().then(s => {
    console.log(s));
    console.log("next step");
  }
}
```