# Pre-map data gathered via multiple async Axios calls into deconstructor

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, axios

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35612484/10406502) neat way of gathering multiple data from a web api via axios. However, the actual result of the axios call stays in the `data` property of the result. Is there an easy way to put the content of the data property into the deconstructed result, instead of the actual Axios object?

Here's my current code:

```js
const [svcResp, allColumns] = await Promise.all([
    this.$http.get('Picking/ViewerSettings'),
    this.$http.get('Settings/SourceColumns')
]);
```

An *untested* idea would be something like this, but woud that work and would that be ideal?

```js
const [svcResp, allColumns] = await Promise.all([
    (await this.$http.get('Picking/ViewerSettings')).data,
    (await this.$http.get('Settings/SourceColumns')).data
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer that uses [array as well as object deconstructors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). I don't know, if this is an ideal solution, though:

```js
const [{ data: svcResp }, { data: allColumns }] = await Promise.all([
    this.$http.get('Picking/ViewerSettings'),
    this.$http.get('Settings/SourceColumns')
]);
```