# async functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have below function inside an async function.

```
await saveStock(stock).then((res) => {
 addDrugToStock(stockDrug)
  addSupplierToStock(stockSupplier)

});
```

When I run this it always saveStock function gives appropriate results. but the other two functions are not executing properly. Sometimes `addDrugToStock` is working. In other times `adSupplierToStock` is working. How can I run both `addDrugToStock` and `addSupplierToStock` at a same time.

Comment: `How can I **run** both... at a same time`. You cannot **run** but you can get the values at the same time

Comment: Use Promise.all for parallel function call https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612428/call-async-await-functions-in-parallel

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute both Promise objects and wait for both of them, then you need to use Promise.all: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 1):

When using [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) operators you don't have to implement the `.then()` or `.catch()` handlers, just write code the synchronous way. Otherwise, you can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to handle multiple independent Promises.

```
try {
   // Equal to .then() in regular Promises

   const response = await saveStock(stock);

   addDrugToStock(stockDrug);
   addSupplierToStock(stockSupplier);
} catch (e) {
   // Equal to .catch() in regular Promises
}
```