# How to use Async in Angular

Tags: angular, asynchronous, async-await

Lets say I want to make 2 http calls which returns data and I want to call a function only after both the http calls have returned data so I can merge both the data.

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getData();
  }



getData() {

this.func1();
this.func2();
this.func3();

}

async func1() {
 this.service.call1().subscribe((data) => {
    this.data1 = data;
  });

}

async func2() {
  this.service.call2().subscribe((data) => {
    this.data2 = data;
  });
}

func3() {
//this should only get called when func1 and func2 have finished their http calls.
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that isn't just a repetition of information available from the tags. Your title should describe the problem you're having or question you're asking in a way that will have meaning to a future user of this site who is scanning a list of search results trying to find a solution to their problem. Your current title does nothing in that regard - it's just a regurgitation of the tags.

Comment: @Jay  Not sure why you changed the accepted answer. Was there anything missing in my answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using RxJS [forkJoin](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin) to achive what you are trying to do.

> forkJoin will wait for all passed observables to emit and complete and
> then it will emit an array or an object with last values from
> corresponding observables.

In angular you `subscribe` (await) to the values of an observable to receive data. In your example, anything in the `subscribe` would be executed once the response has been received from the server.

---

##### If `func3` is not an Observable

```
forkJoin([this.func1(),this.func2()]).subscribe(results => {
    let data1 = results[0];
    let data 2 = results[1];
    this.func3();
});
```

---

##### If `func3` is an Observable you have to pipe your calls

```
this.subscription.add(
        forkJoin([this.func1(),this.func2()])
            .pipe(
                switchMap(results => {
                    let data1 = results[0];
                    let data2 = results[1];
                    return func3();  
                 }
            ))
            .subscribe((value3) => {
                // value returned from the func3() observable
            })
    );
```

Note: Don't forget to unsubscribe all your subscriptions `onDestroy`.

Comment: I use `try catch` with `async await` all the time in Angular TypeScript.  Subscribing creates chains of callbacks within each other.

Comment: @xinthose edited the async await comment. I manage the subscription chain using RxJS.

Answer (score 2):

here is the latest syntax in angular

```
    forkJoin([httpcall1,httpcall2... httpcalln])
          .subscribe((resultArray) => {

            //once the data are recived they will be in the result array in order of the call
            console.log(resultArray[0]);
            console.log(resultArray[1]);
            
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can call func2 inside func1 after getting the data, and func3 inside func2 so it will work one by one

```
getData() {
this.func1();
}

func1() {
this.service.call1().subscribe((data) => {
   this.data1 = data;
this.func2();
});

func2() {
this.service.call2().subscribe((data) => {
   this.data2 = data;
this.func3();
});

func3() {
// Your code here
}
```

Comment: I am trying to understand how to use async/await in this situation

Comment: I found this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35612484/7137373

Comment: Never subscribe to an observable inside a subscribe! You will run into race conditions that'll fail randomly.