# How to run 2 for await loops in parallel?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have this code:

```js
for await (const thing of signal()) {
    // logic
}

for await (const thing of anotherSignal()) {
    // logic
}
```

The problem is that these `for await`s run forever. So the second one never executes. Is there a way to make these 2 loops run in parallel?

Comment: See `Promise.all` https://stackoverflow.com/a/35612484/4781975

Comment: In parallel as in two threads or just running and reporting ASAP but leaving time for the other loop to also work?

Comment: @Zooly OP indicates those functions supply infinite promises. You cannot wait for all of them to finish.

Comment: If they never finish just put them both inside an async function and run, but you will want to also handle errors inside these functions.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to switch to a different abstraction, Observables in particular (e.g. https://rxjs.dev/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't wait for first task to complete, Run them parallel, Like So:

```js
let delay = ms => new Promise(ok => setTimeout(ok, ms));
async function* infinit_iter() {
  for (let i = 0;; i++) {
    await delay(3000)
    yield i
  }
}

async function run(name, iter) {
  for await (let i of iter)
    console.log(name, i)
}

run("signal:", infinit_iter())
run("anotherSignal:", infinit_iter())
```

Comment: What does "on demand" mean?