# Vue 2 await before vairables

Tags: javascript, async-await, vuejs2

In javascript async await function we can write something like this:

```js
const campaigns = await this.$api.campaigns.getCampaigns({all});
const campaigns2 = await this.$api.campaigns.getCampaigns({all});
const campaigns3 = await this.$api.campaigns.getCampaigns({all});
```

It causes that campaigns2 and campaigns3 will wait for the end of first request.
In javascript there should be also possible something like this:

```js
const campaigns = this.$api.campaigns.getCampaigns({all});
const campaigns2 = this.$api.campaigns.getCampaigns({all});
const campaigns3 = this.$api.campaigns.getCampaigns({all});

await campaigns;
await campaigns2;
await campaigns3;

this.campaigns = campaigns3.data.data;
```

This code should make 3 paralel requests for campaigns1,2,3 variables where campaigns2 and campaigns3 dont have to wait for the end of promisse of first request is done. It is possible but in Vue 2 it does not work. It throws me an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')

Can somebody tell me please why? Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking to use something like Promise.all? I don‘t know what the api is sending back but you need to call .json() on the response also

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call async/await functions in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612428/call-async-await-functions-in-parallel)

Comment: This is really valid javascript syntax. But it does not work in Vue 2.

Comment: `campaigns3` is a promise, and will always be a promise.  So when you want the resolved values you need `await`,.  `this.campaigns = (await campaigns3).data.data;`  But like pointed out, `Promise.all` would be a better fit for parallel Promises anyway.

Comment: It doesnt have to do with vue2, at the time you try to get data, campaigns.data is still undefined. You might need to call .json() on it first

Comment: [Do not use the second pattern!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46889290/1048572) Use `Promise.all` instead if you want to wait for multiple things at once

Comment: Ok so I will use Promise.all(). It seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
await campaigns;
```

will indeed wait for the Promise to resolve, but the statement makes no change to the value of `campaigns`. It remains the Promise object, not whatever it is you want back from the API - the promise does not have a `.data` property.

If you want the value, you have to both await the promise completion *and* save the promise result somewhere:

```
let c = await campaigns;
```

Then use `c.data.…`.

Comment: No there should be a value.

Comment: @Čamo have you tried it? There *is* a value, but `campaigns` will still be the Promise object.  Some code in your API will pass a value to `resolve()`, but if you don't save that value somewhere, it's gone. It's like having a `.then()` callback that ignores its parameter.

Comment: It seems you are right. Then better way is to use Promise.all(). Thanks you.