# Racing Javascript promises while ensuring all promises complete

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, promise, cloudflare-workers

I need to get the result of a Javascript Promise that returns the *fastest*, but I want to continue invoking the logic encapsulated within the other 2 "losing" promises, irrespective of who wins. Example below.

```js
// The 3 promises I care about
const fetchFromGoogle: Promise<T> = googlePromise()
const fetchFromAmazon: Promise<T> = amazonPromise()
const fetchFromCloudflare: Promise<T> = cloudflarePromise()

// The promise that invoked its logic the fastest
const winner: T = Promise.race([fetchFromGoogle, fetchFromAmazon, fetchFromCloudflare])
```

In this scenario, if `fetchFromAmazon` call wins in terms of speed, then I would return the result to the client, but continue running the other two promises async.

This is being executed from within a `Cloudflare Worker` and the ability to return the winning promise whilst continuing the evaluation of the other functions will be supported via the `waitUntil` API linked below.

I've evaluated two options:

1. Some Javascript API that I'm unaware of that can do this for me
2. Use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42896456/get-which-promise-completed-in-promise-race) to determine which promises lost and run them using `Cloudflare Workers` [context.waitUntil](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/runtime-apis/fetch-event/#waituntil) call which will ensure that the logic will continue evaluating despite having returned the result back to the client.

It's in my understanding `Promise.All` would not satisfy this criteria because I would never early return the winning promise as we wait for all 3 to complete.

Comment: Take a look at the source of `Promise.race`. It's very easy to implement, and not some kind of magic API that only browsers can provide. It just loops through your array and calls `then()` on each promise. That's where you should start.

Comment: @Evert Any opinions on my proposed solution underneath (2). I assume that's probably the best in my eyes as it implies I kind of pick apart `Promise.race`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just combine a `.then()` handler with `Promise.race()`.  The `.then()` handler lets you handle each result individually.  The `Promise.race()` tells you when the first one is done (and optionally what its value was):

```
// The 3 promises I care about
const fetchFromGoogle: Promise<T> = googlePromise().then(result => { 
    /* process this one here whenever it completes */
    return someValue;
});
const fetchFromAmazon: Promise<T> = amazonPromise().then(result => { 
    /* process this one here whenever it completes */
    return someValue;
});
const fetchFromCloudflare: Promise<T> = cloudflarePromise().then(result => { 
    /* process this one here whenever it completes */
    return someValue;
});

// Tells you when the first one is done and what its value was
const winner: T = await Promise.race([fetchFromGoogle, fetchFromAmazon, fetchFromCloudflare]);
```

Keep in mind that `Promise.race()` tracks the first promise to settle (success or failure) - it does not give you the first promise to fulfill.  So, if the first promise to settle rejects, then that's what `Promise.race()` will give you (the rejected promise).

You can use [`Promise.any()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any) instead to get the first fulfilled promise.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize until after that the promises that don't win still continue execution, which is good to know. Any suggestions on incorporating `context.waitUntil` into this design? Because this is an HTTP handler, I need to ensure the other two promises continue execution after returning to the client. While your solution allows manipulation of the reponse, there is not a guarantee that they will continue after returning from the handler.

Comment: btw, thanks for clarifying `race` vs `any`. I forgot about that distinction, which would cause a bit of trouble for me!

Comment: @user38643 - I don't really know the environment that needs `context.waitUntil`, but you could do a separate `Promise.allSettled([fetchFromGoogle, fetchFromAmazon, fetchFromCloudflare])` with `context.waitUntil` if you somehow need to tell it to keep the request going until all the promises have settled.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure that would satisfy this requirement as the resultant promise wouldn't be fulfilled until they all complete. Maybe the best/only solution is a promise inside ctx.waitUntil that is a sleep timer.

Comment: In JavaScript you can use the same promise in multiple places, so you can do both `waitUntil(Promise.allSettled([a, b])` _and_ `winner = await Promise.race([a, b])`.

Comment: @user38643 - As Kenton mentioned, you can use the same promises in two separate operations.  Use the `Promise.race()` or `Promise.any()` to tell you which one completes first and use the `Promise.allSettled()` with `waitUntil` to keep your request handler alive even after you've sent the response.

Comment: To clarify, this won't invoke the same function multiple times, right? In Kenton's example, if I race [a,b] and then wrap [a,b] in promise.allSettled, I won't reinvoke a or b, correct?

Comment: @user38643 - Correct.  `a` and `b` are just promises.  They don't run anything.  They're just a notification system.  The underlying operation was run once and created the promise.  You can then use that promise for multiple things.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for taking the time to explain all of this. Hope you enjoy your day