# Execute at most N tasks in parallel using JS promises or generators

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator, es6-promise

I want to implement a JS class that executes at most N tasks in parallel using JS promises or generators. Something like

```
class Executor {
    constructor(numberOfMaxTasks) {
    ...
    }

    next(task) {
    ...
    }

    done(onDone) {
    ...
    }
}

....
const executor = new Executor(2);
executor.next(task1).next(task2).next(task3).done(onDone);
```

task1 and task 2 should be executed in parallel while task3 should wait until one of the previous tasks finises. When all tasks finish onDone callback is executed.

I was trying to implement it using promises but I failed. I'm new to generators and currently have no idea if they can help here. This is for learning purposes mostly, that's why I don't want to use any third party libraries, just native JS. Any hint would be great, thanks in advance!

Comment: You know that JavaScript doesn't run code in parallel unless you're spawning WebWorkers or the node.js equivalent, right? Promises and other async stuff allows you to run code while non-JavaScript stuff (network IO, etc) goes on in the background.

Comment: Show us what you tried, please.

Comment: Don't use generators for asynchronous code any more. Go right for `async`/`await` syntax.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limited parallelism with async/await](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39195441/1048572)

Comment: @Touffy Yes, you are right. Maybe parallel is not the best word here. I was a little bit confused by this title: https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/run-n-promises-in-parallel/. Probably asynchronous instead of parallel would be better.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd better to use [bluebird promise library](http://bluebirdjs.com/).

For example, [bluebird provides `map` function](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html#map-option-concurrency) which can do what you want:

- in first argument you can specify array of data required for task execution
- in second argument you can specify mapper function which can actually run your task and return the promise
- in third argument you can specify "most N tasks at the time" with `{ concurrency: N }` object.

Note that for `bluebird.map` function the order of execution doesn't guaranteed. The only guaranteed that result of `bluebird.map` will be promise fulfilled with array of results in same order.

Using that function you can rewrite your code without `Executor` class (example is for node.js):

```js
const Promise = require('bluebird')
const os = require('os')
const task1Data = 1000
const task2Data = 5000
const task3Data = 3000

const tasksData = [ task1Data, task2Data, task3Data ]
function taskExecutorMapper(taskData) {
  // here is place for your code that actually runs
  // asynchronous operation based on taskData and returns promise
  // I'll use setTimeout here for emulate such operation
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(resolve, taskData)
  }
}
const tasksPromise = Promise.map(
  tasksData,
  taskExecutionMapper,
  { concurrency: os.cpus().length })
  .then(onDone)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had to solve a quiz for an interview similar to what you want to achieve, but based in **Node.js**.
  The key is to take control of amount of tasks being executed at the same time with a class property (in my example, `this.running`). So for an array of tasks, you run them through a while loop and check in every loop if you have any available slot (controlled by this.running and LIMIT) and then run the promise.
  This code might help you.

```
    let tasks = [];
    let tasksDone = [];
    const LIMIT = 10;

    class Executor {
        constructor () {
            this.running = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                tasks[i] = {
                    id: 'job_' + (i+1),
                    time: ((i % 4) + 1) * 25
                };
            }
        }

        checkConcurrency () {       
            if( this.running > LIMIT ){
                throw new Error('Maximum number of tasks ['+LIMIT+'] reached');
            }
        }

        execute (task) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
                this.running ++;
                this.checkConcurrency();
                setTimeout(()=>{
                    this.checkConcurrency();
                    this.running --;
                    resolve({
                ...task,
                        finished: Date.now()
                    });
                }, task.time);
            })

        }

        run () { 
          this.startTime = Date.now();
          this.executeTasks(tasks.slice(0));
        }

        executeTasks(tasks) {   
          while (this.running < LIMIT && tasks.length > 0) {
            let task = tasks.shift();
            this.execute(task).then( result => {
              tasksDone.push(result);
              if (tasks.length > 0) {
                this.executeTasks(tasks);
              }
            });      
          }   
        }
    }
```