# HTTP Request promises and concurrency

Tags: javascript

Imagine a request triggered with:

```
http.get('/endpoint')
```

Imagine 10 requests triggered with:

```
const promises = _.range(10).map(i => http.get('/endpoint'))
```

If I want to execute all the requests simultaneously, I generally use

```
const results = await Promise.all(promises)
```

Now, let's imagine that I want to only execute 2 requests at a time, will `Promise.all()` on only two items be enough to execute only 2 requests at a time or will still all requests be triggered at the same time?

```
const promises = _.range(10).map(i => http.get('/endpoint'))

let results = []

for (let chunk of _.chunk(promises, 2)) {
  results = results.concat(await Promise.all(chunk))
}
```

**If it still executes the 10 requests at the same time, how could I prevent this behavior?**

*Note: `_` refers to the [lodash](https://lodash.com) library in order to make the question simpler*

Comment: Hi, If you really want to run two requests at a time. Why not just execute and wait two requests in a loop ?

Comment: `Promise.all` does not "run" anything. You cannot "execute" promises, you can only wait for them. If you already called `http.get()` 10 times in the loop, you have started 10 concurrent requests. `Promise.all` only waits for them.

Comment: Thank you, that was my question :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limited parallelism with async/await in Typescript/ES7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39197252/1048572)

Comment: A simple solution would be to move the `.map(i => http.get('/endpoint'))` onto `chunk` (inside the loop)

Comment: Yes indeed, I should create the initial array on the parameters of the `http.get` function instead of the result of the function I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) `Promise.map` that allow to configure `concurrency` - the concurrency limit applies to Promises returned by the mapper function and it basically limits the number of Promises created.

```
Promise.map(_.range(10), () => {...}, {concurrency: 2})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mapLimit` from `async`.
https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#mapLimit

```
import mapLimit from 'async/mapLimit';

const ids = _.range(10);
const maxParallel = 2;

mapLimit(ids, maxParallel, (id, callback) => {
  http.get(`/endpoint/${id}`)
    .then(result => callback(null, result))
    .catch(error => callback(error, null));
}, (error, results) {
 //Some stuff
});
```