# Wait for async function and promises in it to finish

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

**My task:** I have a file that contains many items and each item is related to an array of URLs of images which I need to download. I want to download all of the links, I'm using [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-downloader) for the image downloading and I'm using promises.

**The problem:**
The problem occurs when I start to download many images from many items, the program sends more than 4000 requests before the first one finished and the program crashes.

**My solution:** My idea was to only handle about 2 items at a time so that I'm downloading about 20 images at a time. I've tried all sorts of variations with promises and async functions but I'm pretty new to those so my attempts failed.

My code flow is something like this:

```js
csvRun()

function csvRun(){
    for(let i = 1; i <= itemsAmount; i++){  // Loops over the items
        // I want to be able to run only x items at a time
        console.log('Item number ' + i)
        itemHandle() 
    }
}

function itemHandle(){ // This function seems useless here but since the item has more data I kept it here
    handleImages()
}


function handleImages(){  // Loops over the images of the item
    for(let g = 0; g < imagesAmount; g++){        
        // Here there is a promise that downloads images
        // For the example I'll use settimout
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('Image downloaded ' + g)
        }, 3000);

        /** If you want the error just use ImgDonwload instead of
            settimeout and set imagesAmount to 20 and itemsAmount 
            to 400
        */ 

    }

}

// Only here to recreate the error. Not necessarily relevant.
function ImgDownload(){
    var download = require('image-downloader')
    download // returns the promise so the handling could resume in order
    .image({
        url:
            "https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/XKPu8Ylce2Cq6yi_pgyLyw80vb4=/0x0:1920x1080/1200x800/filters:focal(807x387:1113x693)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/63380914/PIA16695_large.0.jpg",
        dest: "/folder/img.jpg"
    })
    .then(({ filename, image }) => {
        console.log("File saved to", filename);
    })
    .catch((err: Error) => {
        console.error(err);
    });
}
```

Currently, the code finishes the loop in `csvRun` and prints out `Item number 1` up to `Item number {itemsAmount}` and after 3 seconds prints out all of the `Image downloaded messages`. I understand why that happens. I want to change the code so that each time only 2 calls to `itemHandle` are being made simultaneously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to have a loop that goes over the images and processes one after another. To then run multiple processings in parallel, start multiple loops:

```
  // Goes over the "data" array, calls and waits for each "task" and processes "runnerCount" tasks in parallel
  function inParallel(task, data, runnerCount) {
    let i = 0, results = [];

    async function runner() {
      while(i < data.length) {
         const pos = i++; // be aware: concurrent modification of i
         const entry = data[pos]; 
         results[pos] = await task(entry);
      }
   }

    const runners = Array.from({ length: runnerCount }, runner);

    return Promise.all(runners).then(() => results);
 }
```

To be used as:

```
  const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

 inParallel(async time => {
   console.log(`Timer for ${time}ms starts`);
   await delay(time);
   console.log(`Timer for ${time}ms ends`);
 }, [5000, 6000, 1000]/*ms*/, 2/*in parallel*/);
```

Comment: Wow, what a fascinating technique! Would you mind cross-posting this to [Limited parallelism with async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39195441/1048572)? The only disadvantage is that it keeps running after a promise rejects.

Comment: `Array.from({length: runnerCount}, runner)` :-)

Comment: @bergi indeed thats better. Also I'm interested on your opinion on https://es.discourse.group/t/why-cant-parts-of-the-spec-be-written-in-javascript-itself/82/2

Comment: And concerning the error handling: `try { ... } catch { i = Infinity; }` could work

Comment: How would I get the result array?

Comment: @Koby27 the result of this should be an array `const results = inParallel(array, () =>  ())`

Comment: @bergi cross-posting seems to be discouraged, a mod just deleted the other answer.

Comment: @JonasWilms Uh, yes, you shouldn't just copy-paste the answer, you'd need to adapt it to the other (more generic) question. Basically, writing a new answer to that question, using the same solution technique.

Comment: @JonasWilms Yes, I guess that was the problem. Also iirc mods are notified when 1:1-copies of answers are posted

Answer (score 0):

with vanilla promises you might do something like:

```
let pending_fetches = 0
const MAX_CONCURRENT = 2

const fetch_interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (items.length === 0) return clearInterval(fetch_interval)

    if (pending_fetches < MAX_CONCURRENT) {
        ++pending_fetches
        doFetch(items.pop()).then(response => {
            // do stuff with the response
            --pending_fetches
        })
    }    
}, 100)
```

with async/await something like:

```
const MAX_CONCURRENT = 2

const fetchLoop = async () => {
    while (items.length > 0) {
        const response = await doFetch(items.pop())
        // do stuff with the response
    }
}
for (let i = 0; i < MAX_CONCURRENT; ++i) fetchLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose your data looks like this

```
const items = [
  { id: 1,
    images: [
      'https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/XKPu8Ylce2Cq6yi_pgyLyw80vb4=/0x0:1920x1080/1200x800/filters:focal(807x387:1113x693)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/63380914/PIA16695_large.0.jpg',
      'https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/XKPu8Ylce2Cq6yi_pgyLyw80vb4=/0x0:1920x1080/1200x800/filters:focal(807x387:1113x693)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/63380914/PIA16695_large.0.jpg',
      'https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/XKPu8Ylce2Cq6yi_pgyLyw80vb4=/0x0:1920x1080/1200x800/filters:focal(807x387:1113x693)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/63380914/PIA16695_large.0.jpg',
     ]
  },
  { id: 2,
    images: [
      'https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/XKPu8Ylce2Cq6yi_pgyLyw80vb4=/0x0:1920x1080/1200x800/filters:focal(807x387:1113x693)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/63380914/PIA16695_large.0.jpg',
      'https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/XKPu8Ylce2Cq6yi_pgyLyw80vb4=/0x0:1920x1080/1200x800/filters:focal(807x387:1113x693)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/63380914/PIA16695_large.0.jpg',
      'https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/XKPu8Ylce2Cq6yi_pgyLyw80vb4=/0x0:1920x1080/1200x800/filters:focal(807x387:1113x693)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/63380914/PIA16695_large.0.jpg',
     ]
  },
  { id: 3,
    images: [
      'https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/XKPu8Ylce2Cq6yi_pgyLyw80vb4=/0x0:1920x1080/1200x800/filters:focal(807x387:1113x693)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/63380914/PIA16695_large.0.jpg',
      'https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/XKPu8Ylce2Cq6yi_pgyLyw80vb4=/0x0:1920x1080/1200x800/filters:focal(807x387:1113x693)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/63380914/PIA16695_large.0.jpg',
      'https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/XKPu8Ylce2Cq6yi_pgyLyw80vb4=/0x0:1920x1080/1200x800/filters:focal(807x387:1113x693)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/63380914/PIA16695_large.0.jpg',
     ]
  }
];
```

I would run a simple for..of loop and iterate over images and download item by item

```
// this function will try to download images per items
const download = require('image-downloader')
const downloadImages = async (items = []) => {
  let promises = [];
  for (const item of items) {
    const images = item.images;
    // dest is item.id/imageIndex.jpg
    promsies = images.map((url, index) => download({url, dest: `/folder/${item.id}/${index}.jpg`}));
    await Promise.all(promises);
  }
}

downloadImages(items);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I still prefer Jonas's implementation for being concise, but i'll add another to the ring. A few features:

1. Results and errors are available in a stable array (based on position).
2. This starts processing another item as soon as the individual worker function has finished, instead of batching things and waiting for each `Promise.all` to resolve.

```
function parallelMap(values, workFn, maxConcurrency = 2) {
  const length = values.length;
  const results = Array.from({ length });

  let pos = 0;
  let completed = 0;

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    function work() {
      if (completed === length) {
        return resolve(results);
      }

      if (pos >= length) {
        return;
      }

      const workIndex = pos;
      const item = values[workIndex];
      pos = pos + 1;

      return workFn(item, workIndex)
        .then(result => {
          results[workIndex] = result;
          completed = completed + 1;
          work();
        })
        .catch(result => {
          results[workIndex] = result;
          completed = completed + 1;
          work();
        });
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < maxConcurrency; i++) {
      work();
    }
  });
}
```

Usage:

```
async function fakeRequest({ value, time = 100, shouldFail = false }) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (shouldFail) {
        reject("Failure: " + value);
      } else {
        resolve("Success: " + value);
      }
    }, time);
  });
}

test("basic 'working' prototype", async () => {
  const values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  const results = await parallelMap(values, value => {
    return fakeRequest({ value, time: 100, shouldFail: value % 2 === 0 });
  });

  expect(results).toEqual([
    "Success: 1",
    "Failure: 2",
    "Success: 3",
    "Failure: 4",
    "Success: 5",
    "Failure: 6"
  ]);
}, 350); // each task takes ~100ms to complete, 6 tasks, two at a time = ~300 ms
```

See the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-browser-4ndbi?fontsize=14&module=%2Findex.test.js&previewwindow=tests) for a full test suite.