# Why the execution doesn't stop at await (async/await JS)?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I am writing a function that should execute all async functions as fast as possible, however, only 5 of them can run at the same time.

I wanted to do it using `Promise.race` so the implementation is not the best. The problem is that the code execution doesn't stop at `await`. I would expect, that `counter` variable would be decremented only when the promise resolves but it doesn't wait for the promise to resolve. The code doesn't stop at `Promise.all` either which makes me thing that my understanding of promises is not proper. The code is below and the function in question is `runPromises`.

```js
async function runPromises(promises, limit) {
  const LIMIT = limit || 10;
  let promsCopy = promises.slice();
  let counter = 0;
  let queue = [];
  while (promsCopy.length !== 0) {
    if (counter < LIMIT) {
      let prom = promsCopy.shift();
      if (prom) {
        queue.push(prom());
        counter += 1;
        if (counter >= LIMIT) {
          let [completed] = await Promise.race(
            queue.map((p) => p.then((_) => [p]))
          );
          queue.splice(queue.indexOf(completed), 1);
          counter -= 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  await Promise.all(queue);
}

// the code below is just for testing

const asyncFuncLong = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, 6000);
  });
};

const asyncFuncShort = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
};

let fns = [
  asyncFuncLong,
  asyncFuncLong,
  asyncFuncLong,
  asyncFuncLong,
  asyncFuncLong,
  asyncFuncLong,
  asyncFuncLong,
  asyncFuncLong,
  asyncFuncLong,
  asyncFuncLong,
  asyncFuncLong,
  asyncFuncLong,
  asyncFuncLong,
  asyncFuncLong,
  asyncFuncLong,
  asyncFuncLong,
];

let start = Date.now();

runPromises(fns, 10).then(() => {
  console.log(Date.now() - start);
});
```

Edit: Fixed. Everything works now. Thank you both!

Comment: [Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)!

Comment: I can't use `await` syntax then I believe?

Comment: Why are you even using `new Promise` here? You can and should use `await` right inside of `runPromises` which is an `async` function already.

Comment: I've fixed it now, but ran into a different issue where only first promise is resolved.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the intent a little bit. If you do go with `let promises = fns.map((f) => f());`, then that "starts" all the promises at once. So they are all waiting for 6 seconds, but simultaneously. In order to start them one after another, you do need to leave them as functions, then call them later on.

Comment: Thank you. The code now works as expected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limited parallelism with async/await in ES8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39197252/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fns` array is a list of functions. Those functions return `Promise` objects. You are then passing that list of functions to your `runPromises` function, which appears to want to take a list of `Promise` objects as an argument. But you are passing it a list of functions.

My suggestions are either

- change the `runPromises` function so that it actually calls `prom()` at some point (or just use a map, like `const r = await Promise.all(queue.map((fn) => { return fn(); }));`), or
- change the definition of `fns` to something like `let fns = [ asyncFuncLong(), asyncFuncShort(), asyncFuncLong(), ... ];`.

Comment: The second suggestion does not work, as that runs all the calls immediately.

Comment: The functions immediately return Promise objects, which represent asynchronous tasks that have not necessarily finished executing.

Comment: Yes, but if you do that all you can do is pass the array of promises to `Promise.all`, there is no limiting of concurrent tasks.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I slightly misunderstood the intent of the program. I see what you mean; essentially it starts all the timers at once, which is not what was intended. It does allow you to wait for all the promises to complete, just not quite in the right way.