# Concurrent block in hacklang

Tags: async-await, concurrency, hacklang

Since hack is a single threaded language, what is the benefit of using a concurrent block?

```
concurrent {
   await func_a;
   await func_b;
}
```

My understanding is that one job is waiting until the other job is over.

Comment: I recommend Hack docs' own [Introduction to async operations](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/asynchronous-operations/introduction) which covers how concurrency is possible in a single thread, which I believe is your underlying question. To summarize, the jobs are executed _concurrently_, not one after another. The gist is that the "leaf" Awaitables of the async tree entirely come from waiting on I/O (e.g. MySQL) or on a timer. When all Awaitables are awaiting, the internal Hack scheduler has control and is just waiting for one of those sources to fire, which it can do in a single thread.

Comment: thanks. was looking for that link, but was not able to find it.

Answer (score 2):

[Concurrent doesn't mean multithreading](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/asynchronous-operations/concurrent)

The concurrent block will wait for all async operations (awaitables) in that block similarly to [javascript `Promise.all`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24193596/4419613) (also single threaded).

Without concurrent:

```
await func_a; // 1 sec
await func_b; // 2 sec
await func_c; // 3 sec

// will get here after at least 6 seconds (sum of requests time)
```

With concurrent:

```
concurrent {
   await func_a; // 1 sec
   await func_b; // 2 sec
   await func_c; // 3 sec
}
// will get here after at least 3 seconds (longest request time)
```

It **fits** if you want to make multiple IO requests in parallel.
It **doesn't fit** if you want to [run multiple CPU jobs](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/asynchronous-operations/introduction#limitations).